# How to check if a shell is login/interactive/batch

Tags: shell

I think I understand the differences between an interactive, a login and a batch shell. See the following links for more help:

- [What is the difference between a 'Login' and an 'Interactive' bash shell](https://serverfault.com/questions/8882/what-is-the-difference-between-a-login-and-an-interactive-bash-shell) (from the sister site: [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/))
- [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38175/80216)
- [2.1: Types of shell: interactive and login shells](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide02.html#l7) (from *A User's Guide to the Z-Shell*)

My question is, how can I test with a command/condition if I am on an interactive, a login or a batch shell?

I am looking for a command or condition (that returns `true` or `false`) and that I could also place in an `if` statement. For example:

```
if [[ condition ]]
   echo "This is a login shell"
fi
```

Comment: There is yet another question: Are STDIN and/or STDOUT connected to a tty (terminal) or a pipe (file or process)?  This is a related but distinct test as described in some of the below comments.

Answer (score 268, accepted):

I'm assuming a `bash` shell, or similar, since there is no shell listed in the tags.

#### To check if you are in an interactive shell:

```
[[ $- == *i* ]] && echo 'Interactive' || echo 'Not interactive'
```

#### To check if you are in a login shell:

```
shopt -q login_shell && echo 'Login shell' || echo 'Not login shell'
```

By "batch", I assume you mean "not interactive", so the check for an interactive shell should suffice.

Comment: For `zsh` users, checking for a login shell can be done with: `if [[ -o login ]] ...`

Comment: If you want to know if a "user" ran your program versus "cron".  [[ TERM=="dumb" ]] && echo "Running in cron.

Comment: @ErikAronesty Not all dumb terminals are cron sessions.

Comment: Also for zsh users, to check for interactive sessions: [[ -o interactive ]]

Comment: “I'm assuming a bash shell, or similar, since there is no shell listed in the tags.” – The logic of this statement is truly beautiful! :)

Comment: In older versions of Bash, `set +i` or `set -i` would change the value of `$-`, thus invalidating this test for interactiveness.  In Bash 4.4 (and possibly 4.3; not sure) that bug is fixed and they correctly return errors.

Comment: Love this. Added it to my .bash* files so I get an echo everytime the shell starts - https://gist.github.com/hamiltont/8c92a17c247728f7bb79427cc0c7cb3e

Comment: More portably: `case "$-" in *i*) echo Y ;; esac`

Comment: @NickBull That only checks for interactive, which is not quite the same as being a login shell.

Comment: @ErikE You're dead right, there should also be a check for a leading `-` in that previous comment. A year on, I'm questioning how portable that actually is, maybe I've just forgotten though :)

Comment: Handy _alias_ `check-shell-state` for your `.bashrc`/`.bash_aliases`: `alias check-shell-state="[[ $- == *i* ]] && echo 'Interactive' || echo 'Not interactive'; shopt -q login_shell && echo 'Login shell' || echo 'Not login shell'"`

Comment: What does `*i*` do? When I run `echo *i*` it just prints all files and folders in the current folder that contains the letter `i`, which I guess is not what is supposed to happen here...

Comment: @HelloGoodbye `[[ $- == *i* ]]` checks if `$-` (the shell arguments) contains `i` anywhere. `echo *i*` doesn't really have much to do with it.

Answer (score 57):

In any Bourne-style shell, the `i` option indicates whether the shell is interactive:

```
case $- in
  *i*) echo "This shell is interactive";;
  *) echo "This is a script";;
esac
```

There's no portable and fully reliable way to test for a login shell. Ksh and zsh add `l` to `$-`. Bash sets the `login_shell` option, which you can query with `shopt -q login_shell`. Portably, test whether `$0` starts with a `-`: shells normally know that they're login shells because the caller added a `-` prefix to argument zero (normally the name or path of the executable). This fails to detect shell-specific ways of invoking a login shell (e.g. `ash -l`).

Comment: *(...) because the caller* – I think there's something missing in this fragment.

Comment: It would be ideal if `$0` always starts with a `-` no matter how it was started. But there is at least one exception: This is not always true with bash _even if_ it is supposed to be a login shell. Try it in your box: invoke `bash --login`, then `$0` still reads `bash`.

Comment: @WirawanPurwanto I'm not sure I understand your comment. Isn't that what I wrote in my last sentence?

Comment: @Gilles: You are correct. Sorry I missed your last sentence.

Answer (score 27):

### fish shell

Here's the answer for `fish` in case any other users stumble upon this page.

```
if status --is-interactive
    # fish is interactive - that is, connected to a keyboard.
    # do stuff...
end

if status --is-login
    # fish is a login shell - that is, should perform login tasks such  as  setting  up PATH
    # do stuff...
end

echo "darn, I really wanted to have to use globs or at least a case statement"
```

#### fish docs ref

- [shell initialization](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#initialization)
- [`status` command](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/status.html)

Comment: -1 for unnecessary editorializing.

Comment: If anyone wonders at @NickBastin's comment, he had a fair point so I made an edit.  The original amount of snarkiness has now been cut in half.

Answer (score 21):

### csh / tcsh

For `csh` and `tcsh` I have the following in my `.cshrc` file:

```
if($?prompt) then               # Only interactive shells set $prompt
    ...
endif
```

Specifically for `tcsh`, the variable `loginsh` is set for a login shell:

```
if($?loginsh) then              # A login shell..
    ...
endif
```

(`tcsh` also has a variable `shlvl` which is set to the number of nested shells, where the login shell has a value of 1.)

Comment: `PS1` does not work to test for an interactive shell. It's almost always set in an interactive, but you can unset it. It's very often set in a noninteractive shell, because many systems ship with `export PS` in `/etc/profile`.

Comment: @Gilles Thank you for the correction and edit

Comment: This is Gold : **tcsh also has a variable shlvl which is set to the number of nested shells, where the login shell has a value of 1.**

Answer (score 20):

Another way is to check the result of `tty`

```
if [ "`tty`" != "not a tty" ]; then
```

Comment: ... or use `[ -t 0 ]` to test if STDIN is a tty. You can also use 1 (STDOUT) or 2 (STDERR) depending on your needs.

Comment: @derobert - thanks for showing me something new

Comment: This is a different test. It is possible to have a noninteractive shell whose input is a terminal (anytime you run a script in a terminal!), and it is possible (albeit rare) to have an interactive shell taking input not from a terminal.

Comment: @Gilles if the shell was interactive, and closed leaving a child `disown` and alive, `tty` worked best to know it is not interactive anymore, while `$-` did not change; I am still puzzled about what is the best approach.

Comment: @AquariusPower `tty` tells you whether the terminal is still present. Even when the terminal goes away, the shell is still interactive. Being interactive is not the same as having someone to interact with — there's a strong correlation but this is one of the edge cases where they differ. Which is the best approach depends on what you want to do.

Comment: @Gilles I am concerned about keyboard input, all my tests are pointing to `tty` working best on this case: I run the script, close terminal and it is still running (as I prepared it to), it checks for `tty` and works without input (instead of `read -t` it uses `sleep`), if I dont close the terminal it uses `read -t`

Comment: @AquariusPower Then what you want to test is not for an interactive shell, but whether standard input is a terminal. Use `[ -t 0 ]`. P.S. In my previous comment, I wrote that “there's a strong correlation” — I forgot “apart from the extremely common case of a script started with `#!/bin/sh` or the like”, which is non-interactive but can be connected to a terminal.

Comment: @Gilles I found at bash info `test -t 0`, it works great thx!

Comment: This works in tcsh specifically, as opposed to many other methods that don't.

Answer (score 18):

**for Zsh**

```bsh
# Checking Interactive v.s. Non-Interactive
[[ -o interactive ]] && echo "Interactive" || echo "Non-Interactive"
#
# Checking Login v.s. Non-Login
[[ -o login ]] && echo "Login" || echo "Non-Login"
```

Ref: [2.1.1: What is a login shell? Simple tests](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide02.html#l8)

Answer (score 16):

UNIX/Linux has a command to check if you are on a terminal.

```
if tty -s
then
echo Terminal
else
echo Not on a terminal
fi
```

Comment: This works in `dash` also.

Answer (score 14):

You can check to see if stdin is a terminal:

```
if [ -t 0 ]
then
    echo "Hit enter"
    read ans
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

`i` is not the correct option to look for. `-i` is to force an otherwise
non-interactive shell to become interactive. The correct auto-enabled 
option is `-s`, but Bash unfortunately does not handle this correctly.

You need to check whether `$-` contains `s` (this is granted to be
auto-activated) or whether it contains `i` (this is not granted to
be auto-activated but officially only coupled to the `-i` command line
option of the shell).

Comment: `s` would be if the shell reads commands from stdin, not whether it's interactive. An interactive shell does not necessarily read commands from stdin (try `zsh -i < /dev/null`, though zsh seems to be the exception here). And a shell may be reading commands from stdin and not be interactive (like `sh < file` or `echo 'echo "$1"' | sh -s foo bar`).

Comment: What I wanted to point out is that the original Bourne Shell does not have 'i' in $-, even when it is intended to be interactive.

Comment: OK, but on U&L, "shell" tend to refer to _modern_ shells. The Bourne shell is generally considered a _relique_ and your own variant is not mainstream enough to expect people to know what you're talking about unless you make it explicit.   The question mentioned `[[...]]` which implies ksh/bash/zsh. You've got a point as a _history note_ that checking for `i` in `$-` won't work in the Bourne shell. But then checking for `s` won't work there reliably either. You'd want to also check for `[ -t 0 ]` or `i`; even then that'd be fooled in corner cases like `echo 'exec < /dev/tty; that-check' | sh'`

Comment: Solaris up to Solaris 10 come with the original Bourne Shell and even sill includes aprox. 10 bugs known to be in the shell since SVr4. So adding a hint on the Bourne Shell is not hat deviously as you might belive. zsh on the other side is not sufficient compatible, it e.g. fails when you try to run "configure" with zsh, so beware to set up /bin/sh to point to zsh. BTW: my Bourne Shell sets -i by default in case it decides to be interactive.

Comment: What `configure` does it fail on? What version of `zsh`? Note that none of the POSIX shells are compatible with the Bourne shell, POSIX broke backward compatibility with the Bourne shell (to the better in most of the cases IMO). Now I would not recommend using zsh as /bin/sh, that would not make sense when you can have leaner, faster implementations like `dash`/`mksh`, but it's good zsh has a "sh emulation" mode (historically being Bourne emulation, now converging to POSIX sh) so I can source a "library" file using POSIX syntax.

Comment: I notice POSIX doesn't seem to require $- contain i (which it seems to require s), I'll raise the question on the austin-group ML.

Comment: About Solaris and the Bourne shell. It was the last major Unix vendor doing that and they've been cursed enough for not aligning with the rest of the Unix world. You'll find [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Fusr%2Fxpg4%2Fbin%2Fsh) and on Usenet the usual advise is to use ksh or /usr/xpg4/bin/sh there.

Comment: Recent GNU configure is not usable for me as it calls /bin/bash for every command if the default shell is not bash. This causes a typical configure run to last for aprox. 4 hours on older hardware that I still support. The Schily autoconf thus is based on the last working GNU autoconf, which is GNU autoconf-2.13. If you try to run this with zsh, it hangs forever with the output './configure:770: no matches found: conftest*'. The second run then stops after one of the first tests with: 'configure: error: installation or configuration problem; compiler does not work'.  Eval is broken in zsh4.3.4

Comment: The cmeline that fails is: gcc -c '-g -O2' conftest.c and this identifies incorrect quiting from eval

Comment: sorry for the typos, too late to edit.... The cmdline that fails is: gcc -c '-g -O2' conftest.c and this identifies incorrect quoting from eval  as '-g -O2' is one argument.

Comment: Do you call zsh as sh (in sh emulation) or as zsh? zsh is not POSIX at all in zsh mode (has fixed most of the mis-designs (IMO) there (most of them inherited from the Bourne shell) like the implicit split+glob done upon variable expansion which that configure script probably relies on). But if invoked as "sh" it should work.

Comment: The method to test other shells is to call CONFIG_SHELL=/bin/zsh /bin/zsh ./configure so this cannot flag that Bourne Shell compatibility is needed.

Answer (score 3):

To check whether a script runs in an interactive or non-interactive shell,
I check in my scripts for the presence of a prompt stored in the `$PS1` variable:

```
if [ -z $PS1 ] # no prompt?
### if [ -v PS1 ]   # On Bash 4.2+ ...
then
  # non-interactive
  ...
else
  # interactive
  ...
fi
```

This I learned here: https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/intandnonint.html

Answer (score 0):

Curiously, scripts launched off the desktop in MacOS have the same environment as those started by hand. (They have their stdin as a teletype tty, they have their `login_shell` shopt unset and their `"$-"` as `ehxB`)

If my preferred way of bringing a script to the desktop is to create a symlink from `~/Desktop` to the script, I can only guess that it was launched with a click by checking if `"$0"` is an absolute path (i.e. starts with a slash).