# Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?

Tags: shell, login

I understand the basic difference between an interactive shell and a non-interactive shell.  But what exactly differentiates a login shell from a non-login shell?

Can you give examples for uses of a ***non-login interactive*** shell?

Comment: I think the question is better phrased as "*Why* do/should we care to differentiate login and non-login shells?"

Many places on the web already tell us *what* are the differences, in terms of what startup files each read; but none of them seems to answer the "why" in a satisfactory and convincing way.

Example use cases where you definitely *do not want* one or the other behaviour would be great.

Comment: @Kal This would have to be a different question, since no answer here actually covers that. Edit : Actually, here it is : [WHY a **login** shell over a **non-login** shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324359/why-a-login-shell-over-a-non-login-shell).

Comment: What makes a program a shell? What makes it a login shell? Does the kernel care?

Answer (score 507, accepted):

A login shell is the first process that executes under your user ID when you log in for an interactive session. The login process tells the shell to behave as a login shell with a convention: passing argument 0, which is normally the name of the shell executable, with a `-` character prepended (e.g. `-bash` whereas it would normally be `bash`). Login shells typically read a file that does things like setting environment variables: `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` for the traditional Bourne shell, `~/.bash_profile` additionally for bash<sup>†</sup>, `/etc/zprofile` and `~/.zprofile` for zsh<sup>†</sup>, `/etc/csh.login` and `~/.login` for csh, etc.

When you log in on a text console, or through SSH, or with `su -`, you get an **interactive login** shell. When you log in in graphical mode (on an [X display manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager_%28program_type%29)), you don't get a login shell, instead you get a session manager or a window manager.

It's rare to run a **non-interactive login** shell, but some X settings do that when you log in with a display manager, so as to arrange to read the profile files. Other settings (this depends on the distribution and on the display manager) read `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` explicitly, or don't read them. Another way to get a non-interactive login shell is to log in remotely with a command passed through standard input which is not a terminal, e.g. `ssh example.com <my-script-which-is-stored-locally` (as opposed to `ssh example.com my-script-which-is-on-the-remote-machine`, which runs a non-interactive, non-login shell).

When you start a shell in a terminal in an existing session (screen, X terminal, Emacs terminal buffer, a shell inside another, etc.), you get an **interactive, non-login** shell. That shell might read a shell configuration file (`~/.bashrc` for bash invoked as `bash`, `/etc/zshrc` and `~/.zshrc` for zsh, `/etc/csh.cshrc` and `~/.cshrc` for csh, the file indicated by the `ENV` variable for POSIX/XSI-compliant shells such as dash, ksh, and bash when invoked as `sh`, `$ENV` if set and `~/.mkshrc` for mksh, etc.).

When a shell runs a script or a command passed on its command line, it's a **non-interactive, non-login** shell. Such shells run all the time: it's very common that when a program calls another program, it really runs a tiny script in a shell to invoke that other program. Some shells read a startup file in this case (bash runs the file indicated by the `BASH_ENV` variable, zsh runs `/etc/zshenv` and `~/.zshenv`), but this is risky: the shell can be invoked in all sorts of contexts, and there's hardly anything you can do that might not break something.

<sup>†</sup> I'm simplifying a little, see the manual for the gory details.

Comment: Could you give example how to run `bash` as a non-interactive login shell?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost `echo $- | bash -lx`

Comment: I don't know if this is true in general, but I want to note that when I open a new terminal (on osx using default settings), I get a login shell even though I never type in my username or password.

Comment: @KevinWheeler On OSX, by default, the Terminal application runs a login shell. (As I explain, the program that starts the shell decides whether the shell acts as a login shell.) That's not the normal way to do things.

Comment: Is it possible for there to be a login shell that's not interactive?

Comment: I open a new terminal in GNOME. I have to login. Why is this a non-login shell?

Comment: @Elijah You didn't type your password when opening a terminal, did you? A login shell is one that's started as a consequence of logging in.

Comment: If I run a script from bash, (ie:  ./foo.sh), is it a non-interactive, non-login shell, right?

Comment: @IAmJulianAcosta Yes

Comment: @Gilles I know that is offtopic, but I was trying last night to understand this and foo.sh had the following command: `echo $FOO`, and `$FOO` is defined in `~/.profile`. Why did it printed the value of `$FOO` if is a non-interactive, non-login shell?

Comment: @IAmJulianAcosta If `FOO` is an environment variable (i.e. `.profile` contains `export FOO=something`) then it's available to all subprocesses, including `foo.sh`. If you change `.profile` to `export FOO=something_else` then `./foo.sh` will still print `something` until the next time you log in.

Comment: @Gilles For non interactive non login shell (cronjob), should i place environment variable in `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: @daisy A non-interactive non-login shell does not read any initialization file. To set variables in a cron job, set them in the crontab file, in `~/.pam_environment`, or use something like `. ~/.profile; the_real_job` as the command.

Comment: The leading `-` in `$0` is not necessary there for all login shells. E.g. `bash -li` starts a login shell with `$0` simply set to `bash`. The `-` is set by the process that forks the shell, such as `login` or `exec -l bash -li`.

Comment: Does anyone have an example of `as opposed to ssh example.com my-script-which-is-on-the-remote-machine, which runs a non-interactive, non-login shell`? When I run `ssh remotehost $COMMAND`, `/etc/profile` is always sourced.

Comment: @HartSimha If it does, it's because you (or your administrator or your distribution) have configured your machine in a non-standard way.

Comment: The `ssh example.com <my-script-which-is-stored-locally>`, shouldn't it  be `<my-script-which-is-stored-locally>|ssh example.com`?

Comment: @ecerulm `ssh example.com <my-script-which-is-stored-locally` is equivalent to `cat my-script-which-is-stored-locally | ssh example.com`. It's part of the command (a redirection operator), not half of a metasyntactic marker.

Comment: it's worth noting that even though `tmux` starts a new shell in an existing session, like `screen`, [each new shell it starts is a login shell](https://superuser.com/questions/968942/why-does-tmux-create-new-windows-as-login-shells-by-default).

Comment: @rampion One of the reasons I prefer screen to tmux. The way tmux does it, if you modify your `.profile`, you end up with different environments inside the same tmux session depending on when each window was started.

Comment: When I try `echo $- | bash -lx` (from one of @Gilles' earlier comments) I get the error `bash: line 1: himBHs: command not found`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @kjo You're printing the value of `$-` in the current shell and telling the new `bash` to run it as a command. I meant to write `echo 'echo $-' | bash -lx` or something similar. Weird that nobody remarked on it after all these years!

Comment: @Gilles: thanks!  (More amazing still is that the comment where that code appeared has 13 upvotes!  None of the upvoters ran the code???)

Comment: @Gilles: If I understand things correctly, things seem to be different on macOS.  When I start `Terminal.app`, I get a login shell (`shopt login_shell` retuns `login_shell on`), and my `.bash_profile` is read (and not `.bashrc`, according to [scriptingosx](https://scriptingosx.com/2017/04/about-bash_profile-and-bashrc-on-macos/)).  Also, when I `su bob`, this time `shopt login_shell` returns `login_shell off`, and the `.bash_profile` of this other user (bob) is not read (e.g. as evidenced by the PS1 which is not as specified in there).

Comment: @Gilles Just noticed [your comment to this other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119627/345300) that Terminal.app runs a login shell.

Comment: @Gilles ...and I had not read carefully: `su -` with `-` (same as `-l` "simulate a full login).  From the `man` page, it doesn't explicitly say which configuration files are read (`.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, etc.).

Answer (score 93):

To tell if you are in a login shell:

```
prompt> echo $0
-bash # "-" is the first character. Therefore, this is a login shell.

prompt> echo $0
bash # "-" is NOT the first character. This is NOT a login shell.
```

In Bash, you can also use [`shopt login_shell`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html):

```
prompt> shopt login_shell
login_shell     off
```

(or `on` in a login shell).

Information can be found in `man bash` (search for Invocation). Here is an excerpt:

> A login shell is one whose first character of argument zero is a -, or
>   one started with the --login option.

You can test this yourself. Anytime you SSH, you are using a login shell. For Example:

```
prompt> ssh user@localhost
user@localhost's password:
prompt> echo $0
-bash
```

The importance of using a login shell is that any settings in `/home/user/.bash_profile` will get executed. Here is a little more information if you are interested (from `man bash`)

> "When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a
>   non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and
>   executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.
>   After reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`,
>   `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and
>   executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable. The
>   --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior."

Comment: From bash manual, `A login shell is one whose first character of argument zero is ‘-’, or one invoked with the --login option.`. According to this definition, `echo $0` couldn't determine whether a shell is in login shell or not because when we start a shell with `bash --login`, `$0` is set as `bash`(filename used to invoke Bash), not `-bash`.

Answer (score 31):

I'll elaborate on the great answer by Gilles, combined with Timothy's method for checking login shell type.

If you like to see things for yourself, try the snippets and scenarios bellow.

**Checking whether shell is (non-)interactive**

```
if tty -s; then echo 'This is interactive shell.'; else echo 'This is non-interactive shell.'; fi
```

**Checking whether shell is (non-)login**

If output of `echo $0` starts with `-`, it's login shell (`echo $0` output example: `-bash`). Otherwise it's non-login shell (`echo $0` output example: `bash`).

```
if echo $0 | grep -e ^\- 2>&1>/dev/null; then echo "This is login shell."; else echo "This is non-login shell."; fi;
```

Let's combine the two above together to get both pieces of information at once:

```
THIS_SHELL_INTERACTIVE_TYPE='non-interactive'; 
THIS_SHELL_LOGIN_TYPE='non-login'; 
if tty -s; then THIS_SHELL_INTERACTIVE_TYPE='interactive'; fi; 
if echo $0 | grep -e ^\- 2>&1>/dev/null; then THIS_SHELL_LOGIN_TYPE='login'; fi;
echo "$THIS_SHELL_INTERACTIVE_TYPE/$THIS_SHELL_LOGIN_TYPE"
```

## Scenarios:

### Typical SSH session without special options

```
ssh ubuntu@34.247.105.87
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-1083-aws x86_64)

ubuntu@ip-172-31-0-70:~$ THIS_SHELL_INTERACTIVE_TYPE='non-interactive';
ubuntu@ip-172-31-0-70:~$ THIS_SHELL_LOGIN_TYPE='non-login';
ubuntu@ip-172-31-0-70:~$ if tty -s; then THIS_SHELL_INTERACTIVE_TYPE='interactive'; fi;
ubuntu@ip-172-31-0-70:~$ if echo $0 | grep -e ^\- 2>&1>/dev/null; then THIS_SHELL_LOGIN_TYPE='login'; fi;
ubuntu@ip-172-31-0-70:~$ echo "$THIS_SHELL_INTERACTIVE_TYPE/$THIS_SHELL_LOGIN_TYPE"

interactive/login
```

#### Running script or executing explicitly via new shell

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-0-70:~$  bash -c 'THIS_SHELL_INTERACTIVE_TYPE='non-interactive'; THIS_SHELL_LOGIN_TYPE='non-login'; if tty -s; then THIS_SHELL_INTERACTIVE_TYPE='interactive'; fi; if echo $0 | grep -e ^\- 2>&1>/dev/null; then THIS_SHELL_LOGIN_TYPE='login'; fi; 
echo "$THIS_SHELL_INTERACTIVE_TYPE/$THIS_SHELL_LOGIN_TYPE"'

interactive/non-login
```

#### Running local script remotely

```
ssh ubuntu@34.247.105.87 < checkmy.sh
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-1083-aws x86_64)

non-interactive/login
```

#### Running a command over ssh remotely

```
ssh ubuntu@34.247.105.87 'THIS_SHELL_INTERACTIVE_TYPE='non-interactive'; THIS_SHELL_LOGIN_TYPE='non-login'; if tty -s; then THIS_SHELL_INTERACTIVE_TYPE='interactive'; fi; if echo $0 | grep -e ^\- 2>&1>/dev/null; then THIS_SHELL_LOGIN_TYPE='login'; fi; echo "$THIS_SHELL_INTERACTIVE_TYPE/$THIS_SHELL_LOGIN_TYPE"'

non-interactive/non-login
```

#### Running a command over ssh remotely with `-t` switch

You can explicitly request interactive shell when you want to run command remotely via ssh by using `-t` switch.

```
ssh ubuntu@34.247.105.87 -t 'THIS_SHELL_INTERACTIVE_TYPE='non-interactive'; THIS_SHELL_LOGIN_TYPE='non-login'; if tty -s; then THIS_SHELL_INTERACTIVE_TYPE='interactive'; fi; if echo $0 | grep -e ^\- 2>&1>/dev/null; then THIS_SHELL_LOGIN_TYPE='login'; fi; echo "$THIS_SHELL_INTERACTIVE_TYPE/$THIS_SHELL_LOGIN_TYPE"'

interactive/non-login
```

Note: On topic why running command remotely is not `login shell` more info [here](https://superuser.com/a/1224962/766900).

Comment: This answer helped me to understand and see that when I SSH into a remote server with PuTTY it is in fact a login shell and an interactive shell (which is kind of confusing).

Answer (score 27):

In a login shell, `argv[0][0] == '-'`.
This is how it knows it's a login shell.

And then in some situations it behaves differently depending on its "login shell" status. E.g. a shell, that is not a login shell, would not execute a "logout" command.

Comment: According to `man bash`, with emphasis added, *"A login shell is one whose first character of argument zero is a -, **or one started with the --login option.**"*

Answer (score 22):

A shell started in a new terminal in a GUI would be an interactive non-login shell. It would source your .bashrc, but not your .profile, for example.

Answer (score 6):

This is old thread, but I have just found a concrete example of non-login interactive shell.

When I was using VSCode for remote developement on Linux VM, I realized that my environment variables in `/etc/profile.d/env_file.sh` were not picked up by VSCode integrated terminal, even after restarting VSCode and terminal itself. Output for `$0` indicated that it is not a login shell.

It seems like, after connecting to remote Linux machine, VSCode was just starting one main login shell, but for every integrated terminal it launched just another `/bin/bash` process. You see the output of `ps` doesn't have a `-`, but that was inconclusive to decide whether the current shell is login or not.

```
$ echo $0
/bin/bash
$ ps  $$
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 2274 pts/3    Ss     0:00 /bin/bash
```

When I login to server directly over SSH, I see `-bash`, that is a login shell.

```
~$ echo $0
-bash
~$ ps  $$
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 2088 pts/2    Ss     0:00 -bash
```

Then I added shell argument (`-l`) option in VSCode. Now, output for echo `$0` is same, but notice the `$$` (Id of the current process, PID) `/bin/bash` is with `-l` ( `--login` ) option.

```
$ echo $0
/bin/bash
$ ps  $$
   PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
  2309 pts/3    Ss     0:00 /bin/bash -l
```

So, to check whether shell is login shell or not, you need to check both `echo $0` and `ps $$`. Depending on the implementation, output should be either `-bash` or `/bin/bash -l`

Comment: I had the same problem with VSCode getting non-login shell and needed .profile to be sourced. So I followed your advice along with [this thread](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/1671#issuecomment-860505270) and everything went well. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Gilles' answer is great, but was tricky to follow for me, so here's the gist of what I personally needed to know in a simpler language.

- A **login shell** is the shell given to the user upon their login. So only one of it will exist after the user has logged in.
- A **non-login shell** is a shell invoked without the interference of the login process. Non-login shells do not need to be one per login, so you may get any number of them after you log in.

The distinction between the two lets the users *bind* the tasks that they need to be executed **only once per their login** (e.g. some heavy tasks) *to the startup of their login shell*, and avoid having them fired upon the creation of every new non-login shell (of which they might need numerous ones). Things will be much clearer (hopefully) through the two examples below.

**Example 1:**

Create a new user first (DON'T switch to it afterwards):

```
sudo adduser foo
```

then become root:

```
sudo -i
```

and add this line to `/home/foo/.profile`:

```
echo "Echoed on start of $USER's login shell"
```

Now switch the new user using su like this (Guess what will happen first):

```
su foo
```

You won't see anything echoed. You might have expected the echo you added to the file `/home/foo/.profile` to run, because this file is a login-triggered file, but the problem is not with this file, the problem is you never logged in to foo at all (yes, although it prompted you for foo's password).
So although you can switch to other users using the command `su <username>`, it's not a "login" whatsoever. It's just that after switching, whenever you run commands, that user's ID and group ID will be used instead of yours'. I.e. according to the `man su`:

> su allows to run commands with a substitute user and group ID.

So how can we login to a user (and get the login shell of that user as well) when switching to them? We read in the `man su` that we can use one of the options `-, -l, --login` !

> -, -l, --login: Start the shell as a login shell...

So at this point if you `exit`, you will NOT be logged out of "foo", you will be logged out of your own user! So instead of `exit`ing, let's switch back to our own user using `su` again:

```
su <your_own_user_name>
```

now run this command instead:

```
su --login foo
```

and give foo's password. This time, you will see this line echoed:

> Echoed on start of foo's login shell

Now you can run `exit` too, to logout of foo and switch to your own login shell.

**Example 2:**

Add this line to your `~/.profile`:

```
echo "start of $USER's login shell"
```

save, then open a new terminal, you will see it echoed.
Now run:

```
echo $0
```

You must see (assuming you're on Bash):

```
-bash
```

As you see, it's the name of your shell program prepended with a dash, it means it is a login shell. Now run:

```
bash
```

You won't see anything echoed, but from this point on, you'll not be in the same Bash as before, you just received a new non-login bash shell. To confirm:

```
echo $0
```

Now it must not be prepended by a dash anymore, i.e.:

```
bash
```

Where you may want to use this? For instance, when you need to run some commands by passing them as an "argument" to bash. A famous example of this is using "sudo" behind a command that does redirection to a file requiring sudo privileges:

```
sudo echo 'example line' >> /path/to/file/requiring/sudo/privileges
```

Although sudo will run that command as root, still the redirection will be executed earlier (to open the file and prepare it for redirection), so a nice "*Permission Error*" will be printed and the whole command will fail. Instead, you can use a non-login shell as root and pass your whole command to it as a single argument. E.g.:

```
sudo bash -c "echo 'example line' >> /path/to/file/requiring/sudo/privileges"
```

Of course you don't want root's startup files to fire each and every time you execute such commands!

Comment: Something is wrong with example 2. One will only see the text echoed when they put it in `~/.bashrc` and in both cases `echo $0` will print `bash` and not `-bash`, as this is not a login shell.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all the answers here are missing on how to check a login shell (only Timothy is close but still technically incorrect).

`echo $0` is not a surefire way to check it. You can see this simply by calling `bash --login` or `zsh --login`. Even though it's a login shell `echo $0` will not show the hyphen (`-`).

Hyphen indeed means a login shell, but no hyphen does **not** mean it's not a login shell.

A correct way to check

bash: `shopt login_shell`

zsh: `setopt | grep login` or `set -o | grep login`

These two are just examples. I'm sure other shells have their own commands to check shell options.