# How does bash know how it is being invoked?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, login, jails

I've installed `jailkit` on `Ubuntu 12.04` and I have set up a user's shell to `/bin/bash` - but when it is invoked it runs `/etc/bash.bashrc` instead of `/etc/profile`

If you haven't used `jailkit` before here's the gist of it:

1. A "jailed" version of the system root is created somewhere, like /home/jail
2. Jailed users home directories are moved inside that folder like /home/jail/home/testuser
3. Relavant configuration files are copied to /home/jail/etc/ - including a limited /etc/passwd
4. Programs that you want to allow access to are copied to the corresponding directories, like 
   /bin/bash
5. When a jailed user logs in they are chrooted to /etc/jail/ and can't see any files above that

So I have a `testuser` who has an entry in `/etc/passwd` like this:

```
testuser:x:1002:1003::/home/jail/./home/testuser:/usr/sbin/jk_chrootsh
```

In the file `/home/jail/etc/passwd` there is an entry like:

```
testuser:1001:1003::/home/testuser:/bin/bash
```

I've read though the `bash(1)` and so I think the problem is that bash thinks it is not being invoked as a login shell:

> When  bash  is  invoked  as  an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file
>          /etc/profile, if that file exists.

I get that `bash` is actually being invoked by `/usr/sbin/jk_chrootsh` but I don't understand how `bash` is determining what type of shell it is, and what set of startup files it should run.

I'd like to see if I can troubleshoot this - but I don't understand:

### How does bash know how it is being invoked?

ps: I also looked into `login(1)` without much luck.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally bash knows that it's a login shell because when the login program invokes it, it tells bash that its name is `-bash`. That name is in `argv[0]`, the zeroth command line argument, which is conventionally the way the user invoked the program. The initial hyphen is a convention to tell a shell that it's a login shell. Bash also behaves as a login shell if you pass it the option `--login` or `-l`. See [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell/46856#46856) for more details.

As of Jailkit 2.16, `jk_chrootsh` reads the absolute path to the shell to invoke from various sources, and passes this path as `argv[0]`, and passes its own command line arguments down to that shell. In the normal use case where `jk_chrootsh` is itself used in `/etc/passwd`, there is no way to pass an argument such as `-l`. Since the absolute path doesn't begin with `-`, there is no way to make `jk_chrootsh` invoke a login shell, short of using a tiny intermediate program.

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main () {
    execl("/bin/bash", "-bash", NULL);
    return 127;
}
```

I would have expected `jk_chrootsh` to have an easy way of invoking a login shell. I suggest making a feature request.

Comment: Thanks @Giles - you did a lot of research with Jailshell - even looking though the source. I appreciate that.

Comment: @Giles - can you point me to documentation on `execvl` because jaikit uses `execv` and I am having a hard time finding `execvl` - did you mean `execl` ?

Comment: @cwd Yes, I meant `execl`, sorry.

Comment: @Gilles  Does the same method apply to other executables, as in the case of symlink `/sbin/reboot -> /bin/systemctl`  ? Is this the only way an executable can detect its invocation ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy 1. Yes. 2. Yes, in the sense that this information is only conveyed through `argv[0]` (a program could in principle find `argv[0]` in a different way, but that would still be the information passed by the invoking process in `argv[0]`).

Answer (score 6):

`login` calls the login command/shell of the user with its `argv[0]` starting with a `-`. Shells check their `argv[0]` to determine if they're being called as a login shell.

As @slm says, it's clearly specified in the "Invocation" section of the `bash` manual.

In addition, a few shells like `csh`, `tcsh`, `ksh`, `zsh`, [`yash`](http://yash.sourceforge.jp/index.html.en), `bash` and some variants of the Almquist shell support the `-l` option to enable the `login` mode without having to mingle with the first argument. That is not used by `login`, but you can use it if you want to simulate a login shell from something (like most shells) where it's difficult to run a command with an arbitrary `argv[0]`. I've seen it used by graphical login managers.

Comment: Funny you get the accept and the upvotes and we said pretty much the same thing 8-). Good answer BTW.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash). They discuss the differences in how it can be invoked there. The section is called **INVOCATION**. The 2 primary ways it get's invoked are as a login shell (`bash -l`) and as a interactive shell (`bash -i`).

Take a look at this other Unix and Linux Q&A titled: [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell). It pretty much covers exactly what you're asking about.

Comment: I'm downvoting your answer because I think it restates a lot of what I've said in the question. I've even referenced the man page `bash(1)` in the question and even included a quote. Did you read the entire question? It does not ask "how do I invoke bash" but rather "how does bash know how it is being invoked" - for example when a user logs into the system - how does the *system call* to bash actually take place...

Comment: Yes I did read your question. You asked how does bash know how it was called. Your the OP so it's entirely your call. The INVOCATION section I thought explained that clearly that there are 2 modes in which bash can be called. I wasn't trying to tell you how to invoke per say.  It's difficult to explain that there are 2 methods that bash can be invoked as without mentioning the `-l` and `-i` switches. That being said, I think your question is more fundamental, you're asking what is the mechanism which is used to call bash in one scenario vs. the other. Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: Read through this other question I just posted and see if that Q&A answers what you're asking: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell

Comment: BTW, thank you for leaving a comment when you downvoted!

Comment: Several of those answers explain the mechanism of how a interactive vs. login shell is spawned, are you looking for something more?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction - the other question you referenced in fact details out what I wanted to know perfectly - it all makes sense now. If you make some sort of edit to your answer I can remove my downvote.

Comment: Made an edit. Glad you got your question answered!