# When and where $- options are set?

Tags: bash, shell

I am searching for the initial setting of the *$-* variable. From which file and at which point it gets initialized?

Comment: Do you have a particular issue relating to the value of this variable?

Comment: @Kusalananda no, I don't, I have an issue to not understand how things are set

Answer (score 4):

> From which file and at which point it gets initialized?

It depends on how the shell was invoked, and there may be `set` command invocations in configuration files such as `/etc/bash.bashrc` or `/etc/profile` and even `~/.bashrc`. So there's no one file for initializing it.

To quote bash manual:

> `-` Expands  to the current option flags as specified upon invocation, by the set
>                 builtin command, or those set by the shell itself (such as the -i option).

In other words, some of the options depend on **how** the shell was invoked (login shell or interactive shell), some options are set by the shell itself (that is, they're default options), and then there's manually set ones.  The `set` built-in part is simple - that's in your control, for example

```
$ echo $-
himBHs
$ set -b
$ echo $-
bhimBHs
```

or it can be used in a configuration file that the shell will read.

You might want to refer to [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38175/85039) and [Differentiate Interactive login and non-interactive non-login shell](https://askubuntu.com/a/879400/295286). These two posts cover greatly differences between how shell is invoked,but the later post by terdon shows a good example of options set for login and non-login shell. At the same time, you may be wondering how does the shell know the way it's invoked to set appropriate options ? Well, there's a post for that: [How does bash know how it is being invoked?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/78000/85039):

> Normally bash knows that it's a login shell because when the login program invokes it, it tells bash that its name is -bash. That name is in argv[0], the zeroth command line argument

As mentioned, some options are default. For example,

> `-m`      Monitor mode.  Job control is enabled.  **This option is on by default for interactive shells** on systems that  support  it 
>   `-h`      Remember the location of commands as they are looked up for execution.  **This is enabled by default.**

So as mentioned before, the shell can look at how it was invoked and enable or not `-m`, for example.