# Why do 'ssh host echo $PATH' and printing the $PATH after ssh'ing into the machine give different results?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, environment-variables, path

On a particular host, when I ssh into the machine and enter `echo $PATH` I get

```
/home/wxy/bin64:/home/wxy/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
```

and if I execute `ssh host 'echo $PATH'` I see this:

```
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
```

Why is this discrepancy?

Also what can I do if I wanted to see the former result using the latter command?

Answer (score 14):

In the first scenario you're logging into the system so you're executing what's called a *login* type of connection. A login sources the scripts in `$HOME/.bashrc` and `$HOME/.bash_profile` if you're login shell is Bash. These 2 scripts in turn typically source the files `/etc/bashrc` and the files under `/etc/profile.d/*.sh`.

For the second scenario you're only sourcing the file `$HOME/.bashrc`. This type of login is called *interactive*.

You can read more about these in the **INVOCATION** section of the [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

To change this behavior you can include the $HOME/.bashrc_profile as part of the interactive execution to get the desired behavior:

```
$ ssh user@remotehost '. $HOME/.bash_profile; echo $PATH'
```

-or-

```
$ ssh user@remotehost 'source $HOME/.bash_profile; echo $PATH'
```

#### References

- [Why does an SSH remote command get fewer environment variables then when run manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216202/why-does-an-ssh-remote-command-get-fewer-environment-variables-then-when-run-man)

Comment: And is there any way I can have the sourcing from the login type while having an interactive connection?

Comment: @ProgrammingNoob - see updates.

Comment: `/etc/bashrc` is was very useful to me as it loads environment vars (no need to `source ~/.bash_profile`) which need to be visible to some scripts I needed to run via ssh.

Answer (score 3):

Session initialization files are weird, for <s>hysterical</s> historical reasons.

A long time ago, you logged in on the console, period. When you logged in, you got a shell, and the shell would load some initialization file. For Bourne-style shells, there are two initialization files: `/etc/profile` (for all users) and `~/.profile` (for each user). The initialization file can set environment variables such as `PATH`, load applications that you want to run in every session (e.g. a mail indicator), etc. If a shell isn't a [login shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell), it doesn't need to start anything or set environment variables, so there's no need to run any initialization file. Surely there isn't…

Actually, shells gradually gained interactive features, so there's a need for an initialization file for interactive shells. Ksh has `~/.kshrc`, bash has `~/.bashrc`, zsh has `~/.zshrc`.

Remote interactive logins run `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile`. But these are not suitable to non-interactive logins because they may start non-interactive programs. Unfortunately, no standard has emerged for an initialization file for non-interactive logins.

You can run `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` manually if you're sure they won't produce any output or start any program, just set environment variables.

```
ssh foo '. /etc/profile; . ~/.profile; somecommand'
```

If you have parts in your `.profile` that only make sense in an interactive session, you can put them inside a conditional instruction.

```
## (in ~/.profile)
case $- in
  *i*) # the shell is interactive
    newmail;;
esac
```

If your login shell is bash, you can take advantage of a quirk: the initialization file `~/.bashrc` is read by interactive shells, and also by non-interactive shells whose parent process is called `rshd` or `sshd`. Other shells don't have this quirk.

```
## (in ~/.bashrc)
case $- in
  *i*) # interactive shell: set prompt, completion settings, key bindings, etc.
    …;;
  *) # non-interactive shell: our parent must be rshd or sshd
    . ~/.profile;;
esac
```

Comment: Are they run or are they sourced?

Comment: @Adrian They're all sourced. Otherwise they couldn't perform most of their job (set environment variables, set shell options, define aliases and functions, etc.).

Comment: Yeah.  Thought so.  Was confused by your statements _"...run `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile`..."_

Answer (score 0):

if you are using bash then check `/etc/profile` on the host that you are not able to get your expected output. Please note that bash first reads and executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.