# Remote ssh connection not loading the properties defined in .profile

Tags: shell, ssh

Am doing remote ssh connection to one box like below and executing the command.

```
ssh <userid>@<hostname>
```

While executing the scripts the values defined in .profile not loaded properly.

But if we login directly in that box it is working fine.

Could anyone pls help on this ?

Answer (score 1):

As this excerpt from `man ssh` states,

```
When the user's identity has been accepted by the server, the server
either executes the given command in a non-interactive session or, if no
command has been specified, logs into the machine and gives the user a
normal shell as an interactive session.
```

`.profile` is read only in interactive login shells. So everything is ok. Take a look at [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43389/181255). It explains what an interactive shell is.

Comment: but we do have same scenario in different boxes working fine. This is new box which we are facing issue while doing remote ssh values from .bash_profile / .profile values not loading properly.

Comment: @Rajagopalarao It may be about `sshd` or `.bashrc`. Take a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79783/181255 and compare your old `.bashrc`s with the new one. There may be a fix in them. Also you can add more details in your question about the old OS's that do work and the new one that doesn't. Someone might be able to know and point at the difference. The way `sshd` was compiled might have a difference too.