# How to SSH into a specific directory?

Tags: bash, ssh

I frequently login to a server, then cd into a specific directory. Is it possible to simplify these two commands into one?

```
ssh bob@foo  
cd /home/guest
```

I'd like to avoid changing anything on 'foo' if possible, as I'll have to clear it with the server administrator. I use bash, but I am open to answers in other shells.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just put as the last line of your ~bob/.bash_profile file on foo:

```
cd /home/guest >& /dev/null
```

Now each time you log in (whether by SSH or otherwise), the cd command will run. No mucking around with ssh is necessary.

I know you wrote that you'd "like to avoid changing anything on 'foo' if possible," but if the bob@foo account is yours, changing your own .bash_profile should be acceptable, no?

Comment: Why yes, I think this will work great. I won't need to get permission from IT to make that change. Could you elaborate on why you need >& /dev/null ?

Comment: I think that should be `&> /dev/null`. It prevents any error message that may be shown just in case cd fails to change directory to /home/directory. If you want to see those messages you could just exclude that.

Comment: `>&` and `&>` are the same in Bash. The latter style is preferred though.

Comment: Additionally, the redirection to /dev/null prevents the name of the directory from being echoed onscreen, which "cd" may do.

Answer (score 48):

This works with OpenSSH:

```
ssh -t bob@foo 'cd /home/guest && exec bash -l'
```

The last argument runs in your login shell. The `-t` flag passed to `ssh` forces `ssh` to allocate a pseudo-terminal, which is necessary for an interactive shell. The `-l` flag passed to `bash` starts bash as a [login shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell).

Comment: I wonder, would adding -l option to bash be helpful as well? `... && exec bash -l`

Comment: @konsolebox: That's a good idea. I have added that to my answer.

Answer (score 18):

You can also do it this way, similar to @EvanTeitelman's solution:

```
$ ssh -t bob@foo "cd /tmp ; bash"
```

Or if you don't know the shell on the other end:

```
$ ssh -t bob@foo "cd /tmp && exec \$SHELL"
```

Or like this:

```
$ ssh -t bob@foo 'cd /tmp && exec $SHELL'
```