# How is sudo set to not change $HOME in Ubuntu and how to disable this behavior?

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, environment-variables

On Ubuntu 12.04, when I `sudo -s` the $HOME variable is not changed, so if my regular user is `regularuser`, the situation goes like this:

```
$ cd
$ pwd
/home/regularuser
$ sudo -s
# cd
# pwd
/home/regularuser
```

I have abandoned Ubuntu a long time ago, so I cannot be sure, but I think this is the default behavior. So, my questions are:

1. How is this done? Where is the config?
2. How do I disable it?

**Edit:**
Thanks for the answers, which clarified things a bit, but I guess I must add a couple of questions, to get the answer I am looking for.

3. In Debian `sudo -s`, changes the $HOME variable to `/root`. From what I get from the answers and `man sudo` the shell ran with `sudo -s` is the one given in `/etc/passwd`, right?
4. However, on both Ubuntu and Debian the shell given in `/etc/passwd` for root is `/bin/bash`. In either system also, I cannot find where the difference in `.profile` or `.bashrc` files is, as far as $HOME is concerned, so that the behavior of `sudo -s` differs. Any help on this?

Comment: You answered part of your own question in a comment on my answer, but I thought I'd put the link http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell here. I think your claim in **Q3** is because some people set their profile and rc files to act the same regardless of whether they are in a login shell or not. I think it wildly unlikely that `sudo` behaves differently between Debian and Ubuntu.

Comment: @msw As far as the difference between Debian's and Ubuntu's (12.04) `sudo` goes, I think that indeed there is a difference by default. However, I don't bet on it, since I am on a box which has been setup by someone else and has been running for quite a while. In any case, for anyone interested, I found http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18369/issues-with-preserving-home-on-sudo and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/760140.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Sudo has many compile-time configuration options. You can list the settings in your version with `sudo -V`. One of the differences between the configuration in Debian wheezy and in Ubuntu 12.04 is that the `HOME` environment variable is preserved in Ubuntu but not in Debian; both distributions erase all environment variables except for a few that are explicitly marked as safe to preserve. Thus `sudo -s` preserves `HOME` on Ubuntu, while on Debian `HOME` is erased and `sudo` then sets it to the home directory of the target user.

You can override this behavior in the [`sudoers`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers) file. Run `visudo` to edit the `sudoers` file. There are several relevant options:

- `env_keep` determines which environment variables are preserved. Use `Defaults env_keep += "HOME"` to retain the caller's `HOME` environment variable or `Defaults env_keep -= "HOME"` to erase it (and replace it by the home directory of the target user).
- `env_reset` determines whether environment variables are reset at all. Resetting environment variables is often necessary for rules that allow running a specific command, but does not have a direct security benefit for rules that allow running arbitrary commands anyway.
- `always_set_home`, if set, causes `HOME` to be overridden even if it was preserved due to `env_reset` being disabled or `HOME` being in the `env_keep` list. This option has no effect if `HOME` isn't preserved anyway.
- `set_home` is like `always_set_home`, but only applies to `sudo -s`, not when calling `sudo` with an explicit command.

These options can be set for a given source user, a given target user or a given command; see the `sudoers` manual for details.

You can always choose to override `HOME` for a given call to `sudo` by passing the option `-H`.

The shell will never override the value of `HOME`. (It would set `HOME` if it was unset, but `sudo` always sets `HOME` one way or another.)

If you run `sudo -i`, `sudo` simulates an initial login. This includes setting `HOME` to the home directory of the target user and invoking a [login shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell).

Answer (score 19):

Use `sudo -H -i` instead of `sudo -s` to get an interactive login root shell:

```
sudo -H -i
cd
pwd -P  #  /private/var/root  (on Mac OS X 10.6.8)
```

From `man sudo`:

```
-H      The -H (HOME) option sets the HOME environment variable to
        the homedir of the target user (root by default) as
        specified in passwd(5).  By default, sudo does not modify
        HOME (see set_home and always_set_home in sudoers(5)).
```

Comment: `-i` implies `-H`.

Answer (score 5):

This has little to do with the behavior of `sudo` and much to do with the difference between a "login shell" and a "non-login shell". The quick fix is

```
$ sudo -i
```

as can be seen with:

```
$ sudo -s
# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
# echo $HOME
/home/msw
# exit
$ sudo -i
# echo $HOME
/root
# pwd
/root
```

As noted in the sudo manual:

> The -i (simulate initial login) option runs the shell specified by the password database entry of the target user as a
>                    login shell.  This means that login-specific resource files
>                    such as .profile or .login will be read by the shell.  If a
>                    command is specified, it is passed to the shell for execution
>                    via the shell's -c option.  If no command is specified, an
>                    interactive shell is executed.

Comment: Thanks for the extra details, they clarified things a bit more for me. Guess I have to check the difference between shells. For anyone reading this, on the same situation with me, check this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell

Comment: No, whether sudo changes `HOME` or not has everything to do with how sudo is configured.

Comment: @Gilles: So, how is sudo configured? In `/etc/sudoers`, there is nothing different between Debian and Ubuntu as far as $HOME is concerned.

Comment: @alxs IIRC Debian and Ubuntu have different compile-time defaults. You can override them with the options `always_set_home` and `set_home` in `sudoers`.

Comment: @Gilles: Thank you. That's exactly the answer I am looking for, both on why this happens and how to revert it. If you don't mind posting it, I will accept it as the answer. I could do it myself, but I don't want to take credit for it.

Answer (score 2):

Quite popular way of getting root shell is also using:

```
 $ sudo su - 
 # id
 uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
 # pwd
 /root
```

Comment: I use to use `sudo -i -H`, but it failed with installing a global npm package from git. With `sudo su -` it works ! Thank you.

Comment: Popular does not mean correct

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the different behavior of `sudo -s` on Ubuntu and Debian respectively, you could use a `sudo` wrapper (answer to Q4):

```
sudos() {
   local PATH="$(getconf PATH)" root_homedir
   root_homedir="$(sudo -H sh -c 'printf "%s" "$HOME"')"
   sudo sh -c 'export HOME="$0"; exec sh -i' "$root_homedir"
   return 0
}

sudo -k
sudos
{
logname
whoami
id -un
id -ur
echo "PATH: $PATH"
}
exit
echo "PATH: $PATH"
```