# Why is $HOME inherited when I start a shell with sudo?

Tags: sudo, root

I'm setting up a Vagrant box and I noticed something I found odd.

```
root@box:~# sudo --user=vagrant bash
bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied
vagrant@box:~$ export
declare -x HOME="/root"
```

Why is `HOME` set to `/root` here? The home directory for the user vagrant is certainly not `/root`:

```
vagrant@box:~$ grep vagrant /etc/passwd
vagrant:x:1000:1000::/home/vagrant:/bin/bash
```

Everything I found online talked about how to inherit environment variables, not how to prevent it. The sudoers file contains the `env_reset` default. I don't know what else controls this behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a choice. If you don't like it, you can use the `-i` or `-H` option, or change the configuration. The sudo(8) man page says for `HOME`:

> Set to the home directory of the target user if `-i` or `-H` are specified, `env_reset` or `always_set_home` are set in `sudoers`, or when the `-s` option is specified and `set_home` is set in `sudoers`.

Actually `env_reset` doesn't have an effect on `$HOME` under Ubuntu (but see below). This is an inaccuracy in the man page. See [Launchpad bug #889936](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/889936).

**Additional information**

Some environment variables may still be kept when `env_reset` is provided. There are compile-time defaults, and this can be changed with the `env_keep` option; see the sudoers(5) man page for more information. In the `sudo -V` output under root, you can see the list of these environment variables under "Environment variables to preserve:". In particular, `HOME` is listed by default under Ubuntu, but not under Debian.

For more information, see:

- [How is sudo set to not change $HOME in Ubuntu and how to disable this behavior?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91384/how-is-sudo-set-to-not-change-home-in-ubuntu-and-how-to-disable-this-behavior)
- [Launchpad bug #760140](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/760140) about the compile-time default for `HOME` in Debian and Ubuntu.

Comment: Kinda sounds like the `env_reset` should already have solved this. Regardless, using `--set-home` works.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Yes, note that `--set-home` is the long name for `-H` (the option mentioned in the man page). Not sure why about `env_reset`. If it doesn't behave as documented, report a bug.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg The bug has actually already been reported... several years ago! I've updated my answer. It currently seems to be a bug in the documentation, the behavior being regarded as correct.