# Start sudo interactive session in current directory?

Tags: sudo

I'm having trouble with sudo when I try to start an interactive session.  It always changes the directory to the root's home directory.  But I want to run commands in the directory I started the session from.

How can I get sudo to start an interactive session in my current directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer got me over the hump, although it answered more than just my question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91572/177382

The answer to my specific question is to call sudo with the -s flag instead of -i.

```
sudo -s
```

Comment: `-s` does not run the startup scripts `/etc/profile.d/`