# How do Ubuntu and Debian manage $HOME for users with sudo privileges?

Tags: bash, debian, ubuntu, sudo, home

I have a bash script `myhome.sh` containing only one line:

```
echo $HOME
```

The script's owner is a user:

```
$ ls -l myhome.sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user <date> <time> myhome.sh
```

In **Ubuntu 16.04 and 17.10** I get:

```
$ echo $HOME
/home/user

$ sudo echo $HOME
/home/user

$ bash myhome.sh
/home/user

$ sudo bash myhome.sh
/home/user
```

In **Debian Buster/Testing** I get:

```
$ echo $HOME
/home/user

$ sudo echo $HOME
/home/user

$ bash myhome.sh
/home/user

# WHY ?
$ sudo bash myhome.sh
/root
```

I don't understand why inside the script in Debian, if it's executed with sudo, I always get `$HOME=/root` while in Ubuntu I get `$HOME=/home/user`. Does anyone know what have the Ubuntu developers changed?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Both Debian and Ubuntu ship an `/etc/sudoers` file that contains `Defaults env_reset`, which resets environment variables.

However, the behavior of `env_reset` was changed from *not* touching `$HOME` to resetting it to the home of the target user.

In releases up to 19.04, Ubuntu had patched their version of `sudo` to keep the previous behavior (of not changing `$HOME`):
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/760140

This was undone for 19.10, and starting since, Ubuntu does what upstream `sudo` and all other Linux distributions do, and changes `$HOME` to that of the target user. See this Q&A on askubuntu.com for all the details: [How does sudo handle $HOME differently since 19.10?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1186999/551198). The reversal was not done for earlier releases, so 18.04 LTS still has the Ubuntu-specific behaviour.

---

*The following is the old text of this answer, and applies to Ubuntu releases up to 19.04, including 18.04 LTS.*

In Ubuntu, in order to reset the $HOME environment variable to the target user, one has to set either `Defaults always_set_home` or `Defaults set_home` (in which case only `sudo -s` will get HOME updated) in their `/etc/sudoers`.

This bug at Ubuntu tracker has some more rationale on not setting $HOME in sudo:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/1373495

See comment #4:

> If HOME is removed, then e.g. vim, bash, etc., will use /root/.vimrc,
> /root/.bashrc, etc rather than the user's ~/.vimrc, ~/.bashrc, etc.
> While it's a bad idea to run X clients via sudo, they too would likely
> look in the wrong locations for configuration files, and there's a
> chance that X11 clients may not even be able to connect to the X11
> server if they are aimed at the wrong .Xauthority file.

It's a conscious decision by Ubuntu developers.

This answer has more details on the sudoers options such as `always_set_home`:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91572/281844

---

There's a second issue in your question, which is the `sudo echo $HOME` which still displays the user's home even in Debian.

That happens because the shell is expanding `$HOME` *before* running the `sudo` command.

So this:

```
$ sudo echo $HOME
```

Is first expanded by the shell into:

```
$ sudo echo /home/user
```

And then sudo executes `echo /home/user` as root...

This should demonstrate the difference too:

```
$ sudo bash -c 'echo $HOME'
/root
```

Or get a full root shell and see the environment variable there:

```
$ sudo -s
# echo $HOME
/root
```

Comment: This changed yet again with 19.10: https://askubuntu.com/q/1186999/158442

Comment: I took the liberty of updating the answer here, since filbranden hasn't been around for a while. Go ahead and re-edit or revert as you like, of course. @muru, can you check I didn't leave any stupid mistakes?

Comment: filbranden still seemed active on [vi.se], but yes, I'd have edited myself but I was on my phone then. Thanks @ilkkachu!

Comment: Thanks for the edits!