# Strange problem with different versions of bash (or sudo)?

Tags: bash, sudo

Sorry for the inspecific subject - it is hard to boil down to one line. I have several Linux servers, running Ubuntu.

svrA:

```
rgs-pa-bastion-1 root = cat /etc/*release*
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
...
rgs-pa-bastion-1 root = bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
...
rgs-pa-bastion-1 root = sudo -V
Sudo version 1.8.31
Configure options: --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --includedir=${prefix}/include --mandir=${prefix}/share/man --infodir=${prefix}/share/info --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --disable-silent-rules --libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --libexecdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking -v --with-all-insults --with-pam --with-fqdn --with-logging=syslog --with-logfac=authpriv --with-env-editor --with-editor=/usr/bin/editor --with-exampledir=/usr/share/doc/sudo/examples --with-timeout=15 --with-password-timeout=0 --with-passprompt=[sudo] password for %p:  --without-lecture --with-tty-tickets --disable-root-mailer --enable-admin-flag --with-sendmail=/usr/sbin/sendmail --with-rundir=/run/sudo --libexecdir=/usr/lib --with-sssd --with-sssd-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --with-selinux --with-linux-audit --enable-tmpfiles.d=yes
Sudoers policy plugin version 1.8.31
Sudoers file grammar version 46
...
```

svrB:

```
rgs-pa-db-2 root = cat /etc/*release*
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS"
...
rgs-pa-db-2 root = bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
...
rgs-pa-db-2 root = sudo -V
Sudo version 1.8.21p2
Configure options: --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --includedir=${prefix}/include --mandir=${prefix}/share/man --infodir=${prefix}/share/info --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --disable-silent-rules --libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --libexecdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking -v --with-all-insults --with-pam --with-fqdn --with-logging=syslog --with-logfac=authpriv --with-env-editor --with-editor=/usr/bin/editor --with-exampledir=/usr/share/doc/sudo/examples --with-timeout=15 --with-password-timeout=0 --with-passprompt=[sudo] password for %p:  --without-lecture --with-tty-tickets --disable-root-mailer --enable-admin-flag --with-sendmail=/usr/sbin/sendmail --with-rundir=/run/sudo --libexecdir=/usr/lib/sudo --with-sssd --with-sssd-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --with-selinux --with-linux-audit --enable-tmpfiles.d=yes
Sudoers policy plugin version 1.8.21p2
Sudoers file grammar version 46
...
```

On all my servers I have defined a bash function, which I've called **,** (comma) because it seemed cool at the time:

```
rgs-pa-db-2 root = typeset -f ,
, ()
{
    sudo bash --init-file ~/.bashrc
}
```

On svrA (and every else except svrB), I end up in the home-directory of root:

```
rgs-pa-bastion-1 jan.andersen = ,
[sudo] password for jan.andersen:
rgs-pa-bastion-1 root = pwd
/root
```

However, on svrB:

```
rgs-pa-db-2 jan.andersen = ,
[sudo] password for jan.andersen:
rgs-pa-db-2 root = pwd
/home/jan.andersen
```

Can anybody figure out what is going on here?

Comment: IIRC Ubuntu changed the default for sudo resetting HOME sometime recently. Yep, starting in 19.10: https://askubuntu.com/q/1186999/158442

Comment: Once the answer in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/438567/70524 is updated, this would be pretty much the same question and answer