# How do I change the sudo's invoking user's home directory?

Tags: shell-script, sudo, environment-variables, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have two Ubuntu VM's where one is running on VirtualBox (Ubuntu 18.04) and the other is on WSL 1 (Ubuntu 20.04).

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=~
echo $dir
```

When I run the above shell script without the `sudo`, both VM's print my own `/home/user` directory. But when run this **with** `sudo`, VirtualBox instance prints `/home/user` and the WSL instance prints `/root`. I'm not sure why this happens and if there is any relevance to VM's.

I need this to print the `/home/user` directory in the WSL instance even when running as `sudo`. I achieved this by running this as `sudo -E` but I don't know if that's the best method. Can someone explain why do I get different behaviours in different environments?

Comment: Related: [How is sudo set to not change $HOME in Ubuntu and how to disable this behavior?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91384/how-is-sudo-set-to-not-change-home-in-ubuntu-and-how-to-disable-this-behavior)

Comment: Regarding the difference in behavior between the environments - Is there any chance the VirtualBox VM is running 18.04?  On my 18.04 instances, I see `$HOME`/`$HOME`, regardless of whether it's WSL or on my "pure Linux" 18.04 machine.  On my 20.04 WSL instances and my 20.04 "real Linux" hosts, I see `$HOME`/`/root`.  Not sure what changed between the two releases to cause this (yet), though.

Comment: You can consider making use of the env var `SUDO_USER` as well but of course it won't be as "generic" as env keeping.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds the "old" behaviour (pre-19.04 iirc) was the result of an Ubuntu-specific patch I think - see [How do Ubuntu and Debian manage $HOME for users with sudo privileges?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/438564/how-do-ubuntu-and-debian-manage-home-for-users-with-sudo-privileges)

Comment: @steeldriver Now that you mention it, I recall coming across that when investigating some `sudoers` options a couple of years ago.  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Yes exactly. Ubuntu version in VirtualBox is 18.04 and WSL is 20.04. So it seems like this is related to Ubuntu versions I guess.

Comment: Yes, and per @steeldriver's comment, it's a difference in `sudoers` that causes this.  Updating the `sudoers` (via `visudo`) in the 18.04 versions to match the `env_keep`/`env_reset`/`always_set_home`/`set_home` settings from 20.04 should smooth things out.