# Should `sudo less ...` change the ownership of `~/.lesshst`?

Tags: sudo, less

Having performed a

```bsh
sudo less ...
```

... in order to view a restricted log-file and doing some searches with it, I found the ownership and group of my `~/.lesshst` file changed to `root:root` (where `~` refers to the home-directory of the user invoking the `sudo` command, not the home of `root`, obviously).

This is happening on a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 install with `less --version`:

> ```
> less 487 (GNU regular expressions)
> Copyright (C) 1984-2016  Mark Nudelman
> ```

I could find (google) no references of anyone observing, let alone explaining this behaviour anywhere; so I'm looking for either a rationale for it here *or* confirmation that it is simply sign of a bug.

Comment: The underlying phenomenon is the file is not modified in place. Compare [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37177/108618).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is normal.

```
sudo less ...
```

runs `less` as root, but without changing the home directory. Running searches causes the search history to be updated in `~/.lesshst`, which changes the ownership of the file to the current user, root (to ensure the update can be done safely, `less` writes the history to a new temporary file, then renames it; this causes the original file’s ownership to be lost).

If you want to avoid this, you can tell `less` to use root’s history, by telling `sudo` to set the `HOME` variable to point to root’s home directory:

```
sudo -H less ...
```

Another option is to temporarily disable the search history:

```
sudo LESSHISTFILE=- less ...
```

This does however mean that you won’t be able to use the stored search history (<kbd>/</kbd> followed by <kbd>↑</kbd>, or even <kbd>n</kbd> without specifying a search string).

Comment: Having now learned about the underlying mechanics, I suppose yet another way to solve this issue for more `$HOME`-dwelling utilities than just `less`, is to `visudo` a `Defaults        always_set_home` line into `etc/sudoers` as learned from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/673022/which-are-the-advantages-of-sudo-defaulting-to-keep-home) and [these](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91384/how-is-sudo-set-to-not-change-home-in-ubuntu-and-how-to-disable-this-behavior) answers

Comment: Yes, that would work too, at the cost of some other surprises until you get used to it — other tools will also stop reading their settings from your home directory when used with `sudo`.

Comment: This is also one place where the "useless use of cat" may be useful. I.e `sudo cat ... | less` runs less as current user, keeping any history in the user's `.lesshst` file, and not breaking its permissions.

Comment: @pizzapants184, that wouldn't be easily made to work when `less` gets invoked indirectly, like from a `sudo git log` for instance... but directly, yes certainly!