# Why do I not have sufficient permission just like root when running sudo as a user

Tags: permissions, sudo

The below fails:

```
sudo -u chris ls /root
ls: cannot open directory '/root': Permission denied
```

While the below succeeds:

```
sudo ls /root
...
```

I do not understand why. I assume `-u` just changes the `$USER`/running user to the parameter provided in addition to having root privliges. What is the cause behind this behavior?

Comment: Give it a look even [here](https://superuser.com/a/771523/257269). There are some additional words and tests about variables and `sudo -i`, `sudo -s`, `sudo su`...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`sudo -u chris` runs the given command as user `chris`, not as root with `USER` set to `chris`. So if `chris` can’t access `/root`, `sudo -u chris` won’t change that.

See [`man sudo`](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.9.5/sudo.man.html#u):

> **-u** *user*, **--user**=*user*
>
> Run the command as a user other than the default target user (usually *root*).

`sudo` isn’t specifically a “run as root” tool; it’s a “run as some other user or group” tool.

Comment: Okay from what I understand  from the above, `sudo -u chris` is just running as `chris`, rather than running as `chris` with root privileges?

Comment: Yes, `sudo` doesn’t bestow root privileges; it’s being root that bestows root privileges.

Comment: The advantage of `sudo` is that you can use it to become any user without needing their password (or ssh key, or whatever other authentication is in use).  So `sudo -u chris echo 'I hacked you!' > ~/hacked.txt` will generate a file owned by chris and with no obvious connection to who did it. Of course the use of `sudo` will be logged.

Comment: The entire permissions model is based on your user id. There's really no such thing as "me, but with someone else's permissions". (There's a distinction between real and effective user id for a process, but one or the other is used for a particular operation.)

Comment: @RossPresser, or you could just `sudo -u root 'echo hello > ~chris/hi.txt; chown chris. ~chris/hi.txt'. (Or do the same but start an interactive shell in between so the whole command doesn't end up in sudo's log. (Unless your system admin has thought it a great idea to disallow running a shell via sudo, grr.))

Comment: @RossPresser the redirection (and the `~`) in your `sudo -u chris echo 'I hacked you!' > ~/hacked.txt` example will be processed by the initial user's shell, not by sudo, and is unlikely to generate a file owned by chris.

Comment: @chepner The baseline UNIX DAC model is, but most systems have additional permissions models built on top of that. On Linux for example, there absolutely is a concept of ‘me, but with admin privileges’ if you leverage capabilities.

Comment: @JeffSchaller My bad. My intent was clear although my off-the-cuff typing was faulty.

Comment: Just a note regarding sudo not being a 'run as root' tool, this might be mistakenly assumed on Ubuntu as described here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91572/124109. Running `sudo bash -c 'echo $HOME'` would not echo the root user's $HOME but instead the $HOME of the user who ran the command.

Comment: @Chris isn’t that a red herring? `sudo bash -c 'echo $HOME'` *does* run `bash` as root, but with `$HOME` inherited from the environment `sudo` was given.

Comment: Hmm I just thought it's useful context about why it might be assumed, or where some behavior might have lead to this. I personally had this incorrect assumption for likely years even while using Linux extensively.

Comment: Ah right, I see what you mean — the assumption that `sudo` preserves the user’s identity but somehow grants root privileges. That’s not what I meant by “run as root”; I meant that `sudo` isn’t only useful to run with root privileges (as the root user), it’s useful in general to run with any user’s privileges (as that user). But yes, that context is useful to understand the first assumption!

Answer (score 2):

*sudo* will run a command as a certain user, defaulting to root. This does not mean that it will always be root, because the `-u` option selects the user, not root in this case. If you want to become root you can either run a command with `sudo` (like `sudo chown chris:chris ~`) or you can use the command `su` to switch your user to root, then just run exit to go back to your user

Comment: Of course: Even `su` may be used to change the user altogether `su john`

Comment: Or you could run `su root -c "some command here"` to run a single command via `su`. Or you could run `sudo -s` or `sudo -i` to start a regular or login shell interactively. It's not like one only does one thing and the other another thing, sudo just has more configurability and a more granular permission system.

Answer (score -2):

**sudo**:**S**uper **U**ser **DO**
It is a way to grant users the rights to execute system commands.

If chris is the host try this

```
sudo -h chris  ls -l /root
```

-h, --help       display help message and exit

-h, --host=host  run command on host (if supported by plugin)

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 18 23:52 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 18 23:52 Documents
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 18 23:52 Downloads
```

or you can remove "root"

```
sudo -u chris  ls -l /
```

lrwxrwxrwx   1 **root root**     7 Jan 18 20:32 bin -> usr/bin

From http://www.linfo.org/root_directory.html

"The root directory is the directory on Unix-like operating systems that contains all other directories and files on the system and which is designated by a **forward slash ( / )**.

The use of the word root in this context derives from the fact that this directory is at the very top of the directory tree diagram""

Comment: Negative vote. Why?