# .bashrc execute command after "/bin/bash --login"

Tags: bash, alias, bashrc

I have this alias in my .bashrc:

```
alias s='cd ~/Documents/projects/s && /bin/bash --login && rvm use ruby-1.9'
```

How can I execute the right part after it enters login shell (/bin/bash --login)?

Answer (score 2):

When you run `bash --login`, this starts a [login shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell). One of bash's quirks regarding initialization files is that if it is a login shell, it only reads `~/.bash_profile` (or if that doesn't exist `~/.bash_login`, or if that doesn't exist either `~/.profile`), not `~/.bashrc` even if the shell is interactive.

To execute code in a login shell, put it in `~/.bash_profile` if it's specific to bash, or in `~/.profile` if you want it to happen on any log in, even when `/bin/sh` is invoked.

To make sure that your customizations for interactive shells are applied, put the following code in your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
case $- in
  *i*) if [ -e ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi;;
esac
if [ -e ~/.profile ]; then . ~/.profile; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

As a refinement of the answer by @Gilles to get ruby to only run when you ask for it, I would edit a copy of your .bashrc file and tell bash to use it with the --rcfile parameter