# Different representation of bash in 'ps -f' command

Tags: bash, terminal, ps, xterm

[image]

I have two bash running; one is Terminal application that runs bash, the other one is xterm application that runs bash.

With `ps -f`, I have `-bash` one, and `bash` at the other. 
What makes this difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer from this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46856/1090

It means that bash executed from Terminal is login-shell (-bash), when the bash from xterm is not (bash).