# Missing source ~/.bashrc Mac terminal : ~/.profile?

Tags: osx, profile

I need to install Gerris on mac 10.9.1. The website http://gfs.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Mac_OSX_Installation says:

```
Note: make sure that the file ~/.profile contains the line source ~/.bashrc
for these changes to be taken into account.
```

But there is no source `~/.bashrc` as shown below:

```
GNU nano 2.0.6        File: /Users/samirebalta/.profile                       


# MacPorts Installer addition on 2014-01-21_at_11:48:31: adding an appropriate $
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.


##
# Your previous /Users/samirebalta/.profile file was backed up as /Users/samire$
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2014-01-21_at_12:00:12: adding an appropriate $
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.


##
# Your previous /Users/samirebalta/.profile file was backed up as /Users/samire$
##source ~/.bashrc

                               [ Read 23 lines ]
^G Get Help  ^O WriteOut  ^R Read File ^Y Prev Page ^K Cut Text  ^C Cur Pos
^X Exit      ^J Justify   ^W Where Is  ^V Next Page ^U UnCut Text^T To Spell
```

Comment: create the .bashrc and add the required contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What that tutorial is telling you is that the file `~/.profile` should contain this line:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Your's doesn't so just open it in `nano` as you've done, add the line above and save the file.

---

On most *nix systems, when you open a terminal, you start what is known as an [interactive, non-login shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46856/22222) and when bash is started in this mode, it reads the file `~/.bashrc`.

OSX, however, for reasons I have never understood, has set up its system so that when you start a terminal, it opens a login shell instead. Such shells behave differently and do not read `~/.bashrc` but instead read `~/.profile`. Read the link above for more information on these different shell types.

The tutorial you are following tells you to make changes to your `~/bashrc` file and then to tell your `~/.profile` to import `~/.bashrc`. That's what the `source` command does. If you do not `source ~/.bashrc`, the changes will be ignored on your mac.

Comment: terdon thank u so much but I have already added that line but when I type brew install gtkglext it shows -bash: brew: command not found.............Gerris web page http://gfs.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Mac_OSX_Installation

Comment: @user3115779 please [edit] your question to add extra information since the formatting is lost in the comments. You can then @ping me to let me know (just add a `@` to my username and post a message). Anyway, this is a different problem, you don't have `brew` installed. Did you follow the instructions on the linked page to get that to work? If not, please post a new question for this issue instead of continuing it here.