# Can't find rbenv after installation

Tags: debian, ruby

I've been trying to install rbenv on my fresh Debian 7.4 install, per the instructions [here](http://cbednarski.com/articles/installing-ruby/).

I follow all the steps on the guide, and they all work fine: I can use rbenv to install Rubies and gems just fine.

But if I close the terminal and start a new shell I see this:

```
bash: rbenv: command not found
```

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're following a tutorial made for OSX. For reasons I have never understood, OSX decided to make their non-login shells source `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.profile` etc instead of the usual `~/.bashrc` and its ilk. If you have no idea what I'm talking about, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46856/22222).

Anyway, the tutorial tells you to run

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Which will add the line to `~/.bash_profile` which is ignored by non-login shells on Linux. Instead, you want to do this:

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Now, open a new terminal and everything should be fine.

Comment: Oh my god, you're my hero.

Thanks for the excellent reference, as well.

How should I have known the tutorial was specific to OSX? Just keep an eye out for .bash-profile and .bashrc mixups?

Comment: @ChaseMay that's one hint yeah, that's what tipped me off cause I happened to know about this difference. The author does not state it implicitly, she/he probably assumes that it works on both. The article _does_ mention macs but also Linux and Unix so don't blame yourself :)