# Why we can not see a single hyphen from $0 on a login shell invoked with `--login` option?

Tags: bash, shell, login

`man bash` says,

```
 A login shell is one whose first character of argument zero is a -,  or
 one started with the --login option.
```

When we invoke a terminal such as `mintty -` on Cygwin, we can see a single hyphen (`-`) from $0.

```
$ echo $0
-bash
```

But if we invoke a login shell  with `--login` option, we can not see `-`.

```
$bash --login
$echo $0
bash
```

My questions are:

1. What is the role of `-`? Although we can not see it on login shell invoked `--login`, we can check shell's type by just querying related shell options like `shopt -q login_shell`. What is it for?
2. If there is an important role of `-`, why we can not see it on login shell invoked with `--login`?
3. How can we invoke a login shell manually whose zero argument starts with `-`?
4. It is the case for other shells as such zsh, csh?

Comment: Quick hint for #3: Have a look at [argv0](http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp/argv0.html) ([see also this](https://github.com/andrep/argv0/blob/master/argv0.c))

Answer (score 11):

The leading dash in the process name (in `argv[0]`, to be precise) is placed there by the process that calls the shell — `login` or some equivalent. It tells the shell program that it should act as a login shell (read `.profile`, etc.). The shell program can choose to act as a login shell in other circumstances (for example, bash and zsh act as a login shell if passed the `-l` command line option).

To answer your questions:

1. The role of `-` is to tell the shell to behave as a login shell. For bash, passing `--login` on the command line is equivalent.
2. You can see the *role of `-`* on bash called with the `--login` option — it reads `~/.profile` and so on. You can't see `-bash` if bash was invoked as `bash --login` rather than `-bash` because bash wasn't invoked as `-bash`.
3. Typical shells don't let you choose the zeroth argument, it has to be the command name. With zsh, you can do `ARGV0=-bash bash` and with `ksh93`, `bash` or `zsh`, you can do `(exec -a -bash bash)`. In `mksh` or `zsh`, you can do `hash -- -bash=/bin/bash; -bash`. You cannot do something like `ln -s /bin/bash ./-bash; ./-bash` as it's the whole `argv[0]` that has to start with `-`. You could do `PATH=:$PATH; -bash`, but then it has that nasty side effect of adding `""` in front of `$PATH`.
4. Yes.

See also [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell/46856#46856)

Comment: If we invoke a shell with -c option like `bash -c 'echo $0' -bash`, then it will spawn a login shell too?

Comment: @MS.Kim, not anymore that running a script whose path starts with `-`. That sets the inline script's `$0`, not the `bash` process `argv[0]` to `-bash`.

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1 and 2**

As part from `man bash` that you give in your question, the man page said **or**. So you have two ways to start login shell:

- first character of argument zero is a `-`.
- started with the --login option.

and two way is independent from each other. A shell whose first character of argument zero is a `-` **must** be a login shell. But A shell whose first character of argument zero is not a `-` still can be a login shell or not. It is a login shell when invoked with `--login`.

Another way to check a login shell:

```
$ cuonglm at ~
$ bash --login
$ cuonglm at ~
$ grep -- -l /proc/$$/cmdline
Binary file /proc/7620/cmdline matches
```

**Question 3**

A simple way:

```
$ cuonglm at ~
$ sudo su -
% root at ~
% shopt -q login_shell && echo "Login shell" || echo "Not login shell"
Login shell
```

**Question 4**

AFAIK, `zsh` and `csh` is the same as `bash` in this case.

Comment: `exec -a -bash bash` will also spawn a login shell for question 3.

Comment: @llua, If we just set the first character of argument zero, will it spawn a login shell? For example, will bash -c `bash' -bash` also spawn a login shell? I tried this, but it seems not.