# login shell (bash) - how to we invoke a login shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos, kernel

I know what is a login shell and the difference between a login shell and a non-login shell.

But what puzzles me is how it is invoked. It is said that a login shell is invoked with a `-` as  argument 0.

How can we pass an argument to a shell that is being invoked, then argument 0 is the name of the shell itself?

```
# -bash 
-bash: -bash: command not found
```

Okay nevermind

```
# bash --login
# echo $0
# bash
```

I still don't see a `-bash`.

Only when I SSH in, then I am able to see a `-bash` when issuing `echo $0`.
But back to my original question,

1. how does Unix/Linux create a login shell ?
2. What is the "thing" that creates a login shell during the login process? If it is a "login" process that invokes the bash shell during login, how does it pass argument 0 as `-` to the bash shell?

Comment: Related: [Why we can not see a single hyphen from $0 on a login shell invoked with `--login` option?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128936/why-we-can-not-see-a-single-hyphen-from-0-on-a-login-shell-invoked-with-logi)

Comment: "It is said that a login shell is invoked with a `-` as argument 0." This is not generally the case. I guess you read this in the `man bash`, but there it is related to the behaviour of the `exec` built-in utility. The answer in the link given in the [above comment by Mark Plotnick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223056/login-shell-bash-how-to-we-invoke-a-login-shell#comment379095_223056) explains it best.

Answer (score 7):

Programs like SSH, `sudo`, `su`, etc., start the shell using [the `exec` family of system calls](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/exec.3posix). And these system calls allow the calling program to specify every argument, including the function. For example, using `sudo` to start a login shell:

```
$ strace -fe execve -o sudo.log sudo -i
root:~ $ echo $0
-bash
root:~ $ logout
$ grep bash sudo.log 
19124 execve("/bin/bash", ["-bash"], [/* 31 vars */]) = 0
19140 execve("/bin/ls", ["ls", "/etc/bash_completion.d"], [/* 40 vars */]) = 0
```

As can be seen in the first `execve` call, the array of arguments passed to `bash` is just `["-bash"]` - so argument zero is `-bash`.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to replicate with `zsh`, which allows the appropriate argument to the `exec(3)` call to be specified via `ARGV0`:

```
% ARGV0=-bash bash
-bash-4.1$ ps o cmd --pid=$$
CMD
-bash
-bash-4.1$ exit
% ARGV0=imnotaduck bash
$ ps o cmd --pid=$$
CMD
imnotaduck
$ exit
%
```

In C, as done by `login(1)`, the code would run something along the lines of:

```
execlp("/usr/local/bin/bash", "-bash", ..., (char *) 0)
```

to insert the hyphen into the process name. This can be confirmed by either running `login` and `bash` under `strace`, or by inspecting the source code for `login`.

Answer (score 0):

To login as user usertest, do (being root) :

```
root:~# login usertest
Password: 
usertest:~$ echo $0
-bash
usertest:~$ exit
root:~# _
```

That's the formal way in which an user logs in.

Of course, you could allways execute a command for which it's $0 is changed:

```
bash -c 'echo "hello"; echo $0;' mylogthisshell
```

Which could allways have an starting dash

```
bash -c 'echo "hello"; echo $0;' -mylogthisshell
```