# Why does "ps -p proc1 proc2 proc3" show "-csh", "-tcsh", and "-/bin/tcsh", whereas "ps -p proc[n]" individually all say "tcsh"?

Tags: ps, tcsh, csh

I use tcsh (not csh), and ran `pgrep csh | xargs ps -p` to see why I appeared to be running csh. A portion of the results:

```
 1529 pts/0    Ss     0:00 -csh
 1764 pts/3    Ss     0:00 -tcsh
 1979 pts/4    Ss+    0:00 -bin/tcsh
```

I then did `ps -p 1529 1764 1979` and got the same thing:

```
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 1529 pts/0    Ss     0:00 -csh
 1764 pts/3    Ss     0:00 -tcsh
 1979 pts/4    Ss+    0:00 -bin/tcsh
```

Then I did `ps -p 1529; ps -p 1764; ps -p 1979`

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 1529 pts/0    00:00:00 tcsh
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 1764 pts/3    00:00:00 tcsh
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 1979 pts/4    00:00:00 tcsh
```

`ps --version` gives `procps-ng version 3.3.10` and `tcsh --version` yields `tcsh 6.19.00 (Astron) 2015-05-21 (x86_64-unknown-linux) options wide,nls,dl,al,kan,sm,rh,color,filec`.

Why this odd behavior? I'm trying to write a process monitor, and having tcsh take three different forms is annoying.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing two different fields.

Note the header lines. The one with the dashes has `COMMAND`, whereas the one with tcsh has `CMD`. See the *Standard format specifiers* section of the [`man 1 ps`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) man page.

Essentially:

- `cmd` (`CMD`) is the command with all its arguments as a string.
- `comm` (`COMMAND`) is the name of the executable the process is running.

In Linux, the latter can also be set using `prctl(PR_SET_NAME, string)` for the entire process, and with `pthread_setname_np(thread, string)` for an individual thread. `string` is limited to 16 characters, though.

Shells routinely set their name based on the symlink or mode they were executed in, so that the process list looks logically correct. In particular, starting the name with a dash (as in `-tcsh`) is used to indicate a *login* shell.

In OP's case, there are three shells running the `tcsh` shell binary, all three as *login shells*, but one of them is in `csh` mode.

A *login shell* is just a shell in a certain interactive mode; the shell behaving slightly differently to one that say executes a script. Consider it a mode that has bells and whistles to make shell use easier for humans, that scripts do not need.

The OP almost certainly has `csh` aliased to `tcsh`, and the three shells were started using `tcsh -l`, `csh -l`, and `bin/tcsh -l`, respectively. To find out which actual binary a command starts, use `realpath $(which command)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an oddity of Linux's `ps` command. It tries to emulate the behavior of `ps` of several Unix variants, and guesses the variant based on the options you pass. This is described as “personality” in the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html).

Depending on the guessed variant, the default set of output fields is different. In the Linux personality, `ps` shows the `pid` (“PID”), `tty` (“TTY”), `time` (“TIME”) and `args` (“CMD”) columns. In the BSD personality, `ps` shows `pid` “PID”, `tty` “TTY”, `stat “STAT”,`time`“TIME” and`comm`“COMMAND”.`ps -p 1529`is (historically) System V syntax, and in that case Linux chooses the Linux personality.`ps -p 1529 1764 1979`has the`-p`option with the argument`1529`, and two more arguments`1764`and`1979`(they're argument to`ps`itself, not to the`-p`option). With a process ID as argument,`ps`chooses the BSD output format. You get the same with`ps 1529`.

The difference between the `args` column (alias `command`, header “CMD”) and the `comm` column (header “COMMAND”) is that CMD shows the command line with all arguments separted by spaces (possibly truncated), whereas COMMAND shows only the executable name. The first argument (argument number 0) in a program's command line is normally the name of the executable, by convention. However, when a shell is invoked as a login shell, argument 0 has a dash (`-`) as a prefix — this is how a shell finds out that it's supposed to act as a login shell. On this topic, see [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell) and [Why we can not see a single hyphen from $0 on a login shell invoked with `--login` option?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128936/why-we-can-not-see-a-single-hyphen-from-0-on-a-login-shell-invoked-with-logi/128983#128983)

As for the appearance of `csh` as opposed to `tcsh`, that means you ran `csh` somewhere. You might not have noticed if `csh` is just a symbolic to `tcsh`.