# .bash_history keeps truncating

Tags: bash, osx, command-history

My .bash_history keeps truncating even though I set:

```
export HISTSIZE=
export HISTFILESIZE=
```

On my `.bash_profile`. Im not sure when it happens but it might happen when I logout or shut down my computer. Since I have had this problem for a while, I tried setting the same variables on my `/etc/profile`, which doesn't fix the problem.

It does go up to 2000 lines (which is the max I saw before it truncated) but sometimes it just truncates and I notice that later. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You can refer to this: http://superuser.com/questions/575479/bash-history-truncated-to-500-lines-on-each-login

Comment: @cuonglm Yeah, I found that when searching. The person solved it by setting it in `.bash_profile` instead of `.bashrc` which wasn't my problem.

Comment: It seems `.profile`.

Comment: What does it show at `echo $HISTSIZE` ?

Comment: @Sree it echoes a blank line. Just like echoing `$dosifnsdoifjoisdjfisodf` would.

Comment: Could you paste the entry you have made in the .bash_profile file?

Comment: @sree I have already done that, its in the question

Answer (score 9):

`.bash_profile` is only loaded if bash is started as a [login shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell). On OSX, the default is to start a login shell in every terminal, so that's the common case for you. But if you ever type `bash` to run a nested shell, or run screen or tmux, or anything else that starts an interactive shell, you'll end up with an interactive, non-login shell. This shell only reads `~/.bashrc`, it doesn't read `~/.bash_profile`. Since you exported `HISTFILESIZE` to the environment, a shell that's started from a program started from a terminal that ran a login shell will inherit that setting. But a shell started independently will not (which is a fundamental flaw in OSX's approach of starting login shells in terminals.) So a shell started inside a terminal emulator that doesn't start a login shell, or in a screen session started by a cron job, or in Aquamacs, etc. won't have any `HISTSIZE` or `HISTFILESIZE` setting and thus will use the default values.

The fix is to set `HISTSIZE` and `HISTFILESIZE` at the proper place: in `~/.bashrc`.

Bash bizarrely reads `.bashrc` only from non-login interactive shells. To get it read in all interactive shells, put the following line in your `.bash_profile`:

```
case $- in *i*) . ~/.bashrc;; esac
```

Comment: I will try setting it in `bashrc` and see how it goes.
And what do you mean with the first part of your answer? I never said anything about `HISTFILE` or misreported anything.

Comment: unfortunately this did not work, it was trimmed when I shut down my computer today.

Comment: `Since you exported HISTFILESIZE to the environment, a shell that's started from a program started from a terminal that ran a login shell will inherit that setting.` I think I got a little dizzy reading that. I've been having the same problem since forever. I ended up dealing with via an autobackup, but I'll give your suggestion a try.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check all files that are loaded with all kinds of shells. For me, it turned out to be the /etc/bash.bashrc file which included these two lines

```
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000
```

I can't really say why that mattered since I was resetting them in my .bashrc, but by commenting out these lines, I got it all working.

I started seeing this problem after switching to Ubuntu from Debian. Seeing as the lines weren't there on Debian, and that I never saw any problem there, I am quite confident that this is a final solution.