# What does it mean to have a minus sign as the first character of a command in htop output?

Tags: shell, process

In htop, or other commands that show process status, all bash processes have in the command column

```
/bin/bash
```

but one process has in the command column

```
-bash
```

What does it mean?

Comment: That's not specific to `htop`, that's specific to `bash`. It means it's a login shell.

Comment: @jordanm Not specific to `bash` either, other shells do the same.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A minus sign before the command name is a convention that login programs use to start login shells. A login program is a program where you typically type your password and that starts a session for you, such as `login`, `sudo -i`, `su -`, sshd, etc. A login shell is the initial shell of a text mode session.

Conventionally, when a program invokes another program, it passes the program's name as argument 0; command line arguments are numbered starting from 1. For example, when you run `cp foo bar`, this executes the executable file located at `/bin/cp` (on typical systems), and passes `cp` as argument 0, `foo` as argument 1 and `bar` as argument 2. The normal convention is to use the base name of the executable as argument 0. When a login program invokes a shell, it violates this convention and puts an extra hyphen before the program name. Shells understand this alternate convention and set things up appropriately for a login shell, typically reading an initialization file such as `~/.profile`, `~/.login`, `~/.bash_profile`, etc. depending on the shell.

See also [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell)