# Tmux displaying quotes/messages on startup

Tags: terminal, tmux, lmde

I have installed tmux on Linux Mint Debian Edition and every time I start it or create a new pane/window it displays a random quote or message above the prompt. It's driving me crazy and I cannot seem to find where the messages are coming from. Can someone tell me how to turn them off? Here are some of the messages it shows:

> The difference between a Miracle and a Fact is exactly the difference
>   between a mermaid and a seal.
>                   -- Mark Twain
>
> FORTUNE PROVIDES QUESTIONS FOR THE GREAT ANSWERS: #15 A:      The
>   Royal Canadian Mounted Police. Q:      What was the greatest
>   achievement in taxidermy?
>
> Q:      What lies on the bottom of the ocean and twitches? A:      A
>   nervous wreck.
>
> You have a deep interest in all that is artistic.
>
> Q:      What is the sound of one cat napping? A:      Mu.
>
> Beware of Bigfoot!
>
> Live in a world of your own, but always welcome visitors.

Comment: `apt-get uninstall fortune` and then remove it from your `~/.{,bash_}profile`...

Comment: Thank you! That has been driving me crazy for ages. I had to run `apt-get remove fortune-mod`. And fortune was being called in `~/.zlogin` which comes from me installing [prezto](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto), but now it's gone. If you add this as an answer, I'll accept :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those messages are generated by the [fortune program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune_(Unix)), a database of quotations that hails from the UNIX days.

The fact that they are appearing when you start tmux (or open a new window or pane) suggests that they are called for your [login shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell).

You can stop this behaviour by removing fortune: `apt-get uninstall fortune`, and then looking through your shell initialisation files (for example, depending on your setup, with bash check `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`, and for zsh look at `~/.zprofile` or `~/.zlogin`) and removing the call to `fortune`.