# unable to login via tty{1-6} as a normal user

Tags: shell, login, profile

I am unable to login via ***tty{1-6}*** as a normal user. I can only login as `root`.

When logged in with a normal user, the computer displays the greeting message from `/etc/motd` and logs me out immediately.

What could be the reason?

Which log files could be useful to check?

I can login fine with a normal user using **Gnome** on `tty7`.

Comment: What distribution and version are you using?

Comment: Debian 8, but I found out what the reason is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you log in on a text mode console or over the network, your [login shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell/46856#46856) is executed. It reads some system-wide and per-user configuration files; here are the most common ones (if your shell isn't listed here, refer to its documentation):

- sh, ksh: `/etc/profile`; `~/.profile`
- bash: `/etc/profile`; `~/.bash_profile`, if absent `~/.bash_login`, if absent `~/.profile`.
- zsh: `/etc/zshenv`, `/etc/zprofile`, `/etc/zlogin`, `/etc/zshrc` (if interactive); `~/.zshenv`, `~/.zprofile`, `~/.zlogin`, `~/.zshrc` (if interactive)
- csh, tcsh: `~/.login`
- fish: `/usr/share/fish/config.fish`, `/etc/fish/config.fish`; ~/.config/fish/config.fish`

These files may load other files; in particular many distributions set up `/etc/profile` to load files in `/etc/profile.d`.

If any of these files contains something that causes the shell to exit, you'll be logged out without having the opportunity to type a command.

You can add a line containing `set -x` to the top of the applicable file to see a trace of the commands that are executed. (That's for Bourne-style shells; use `set echo` in csh, and [fish has no such thing](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/805))

When you log in via the GUI (on a [display manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager_(program_type))), your login shell isn't executed; however most systems arrange to run either sh or bash and load `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile`.

If you're stuck because you can't log in:

- Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+C during the login sequence. If you hit it at the right time, it'll interrupt the shell just as it's starting to load the profile file and you'll get a command line.
- Run commands over the network. `ssh mymachine.example.com 'mv .profile no.profile'` moves a problematic `~/.profile` out of the way; it doesn't load the profile files because the remote shell isn't a login shell. (But bash is weird: it loads `.bashrc` if its parent is `rshd` or `sshd` even though the shell isn't interactive.)
- Access the account over FTP or SFTP.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found out, that there were some files left from my experiments with `cdm`, so `/etc/profile.d/zzz-cdm-profile.sh` was executed during `tty` login which triggered the log out immediately. Removing this one - fixed the problem.