# Insert empty line between command line prompts

Tags: bash, command-line

When using the command line, often it gets very cluttered. Making it inconvenient to examine past commands and their outputs for example.

I would like to have a newline added each time before the command prompt is shown. Like so:

```
<clutter>
<blank line>
name@machine:~$
```

I use the bash shell. How can this be achieved?

Comment: I prefer this: http://lifehacker.com/5840450/add-a-handy-separator-between-commands-in-your-terminal-on-mac-os-x-and-linux

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by modifying the `.bashrc` file. 
Simply place the following at the end of the `.bashrc` file.

```
PS1="\n$PS1"
```

To explain how this works, `PS1` is the variable containing what should be displayed as the prompt. All this is saying is "set `PS1` to the previous contents of `PS1`, with a newline character prepended". Putting it in `.bashrc` on most distros just makes bash run it every time you open an interactive shell (but not a login shell - see [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell)).

Comment: To explain how this works, PS1 is the variable containing what should be displayed as the prompt. All this is saying is "set PS1 to the previous contents of PS1, with a newline character prepended".

Comment: @Muzer Maybe your comment could be an edit

Comment: @rpax good idea, submitted. Added a bit about .bashrc itself, too.

Comment: Satisfyingly, executing `PS1="\n$PS1"` in a terminal has instant effect :)

Comment: Works totally fine, other than after entering `clear` (or pressing `Ctrl+l`) the first line shown is an empty line. For some it might be a small detail, but I'd much prefer the first line to be the prompt.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [PROMPT_COMMAND](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-PROMPT_005fCOMMAND):

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="printf '\n';$PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

or:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="echo;$PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Comment: Should the first one be `PROMPT_COMMAND="printf '\n';$PROMPT_COMMAND"`? In its present form it dint seem to do anything when I placed it in the `.bashrc` file.

Comment: @Slothworks: Yes, of course, my mis-typing, fixed it.

Comment: More than one way to do it indeed :) Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Slothworks's alternative is better, because yours executes an extra command after every command that is run at the command line. `printf` and `echo` are very lightweight, of course, but it still doesn't make sense to use `PROMPT_COMMAND` when `PS1` will do the job.

Comment: Note, if you wanted to put something in the command that changed every time you ran the prompt, then you want PROMPT_COMMAND and not PS1. This is commonly used with git to display which branch of the repo is active. Google for PROMPT_COMMAND suggestions to see what can be done.

Comment: A relevant search result: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3058325/3262406

Comment: For me this works better than adding `'\n'` in front of `$PS1`, because when I press `Ctrl+l` (or enter `clear`), the first line in the terminal is the prompt, while after modifying `$PS1` the first line is empty line.

Comment: `PROMPT_COMMAND='PROMPT_COMMAND=echo'` works nicely for me: it inserts an empty line before every prompt *except the first*.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative: leave a line in the `PS1=` prompt of your `.bashrc`. Here's literally how I set up `.bashrc` on every linux machine I have:

```
PS1=' 
serg@ubuntu [$(pwd)]
================================
$ '
```

As you see in my example above, username is hardcoded into the prompt. You can of course use escape sequences that [bash](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html) or another shell (e.g. [ksh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171663/how-to-custom-display-prompt-in-kornshell-to-show-hostname-and-current-directory)) provides, but a little more neutral option would be to do use parameter substitution with commands like `whoami` (report your username) and `hostname`(obviously, reports hostname). For instance:

```
PS1='
$(whoami)@$(hostname):$(pwd)
$ '
```

For more fun stuff with the prompt, `.bashrc`, and parameter expansions, check out my answers here:

[How to check battery status using terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/a/501389/295286)

[How can I get my terminals / shells to have custom designs in it?](https://askubuntu.com/a/659985/295286) and

[How to show a running clock in terminal before the command prompt?](https://askubuntu.com/a/526256/295286)

Comment: Why the user name and machine name are hard coded? Would be nice if they were parametrized

Comment: @rpax my actual username is different. That's my name that you see in the prompt. Machine name is also different.

Comment: I meant some kind of `$(whoami)` instead of `usernamehardcoded`

Comment: @rpax oh, that can be done as well. I'll include that into my answer

Comment: Great. +1 in advance

Comment: @rpax Delivered. Thanks for the upvote ;)

Comment: Note you can use `\u` and `\h` for your username and hostname, respectively. You can see more special characters (for e.g. the current time in various formats) [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Controlling-the-Prompt)