# Complete view of where the PATH variable is set in bash

Tags: environment-variables, path

I've read in a couple of places that the `PATH` is set in `/etc/profile` or the `.profile` file that's in the home dir.

Are these the only places that the path is set in? I want a better understanding of it.

In the `/etc/profile` file, as the following comment says `"system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell"`. Does that mean that profile files are the main configuration files for bash?

In that file I don't see the `PATH` var being set at all. In the `.profile` file in the home directory there's this line:

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

That's resetting `PATH` by the looks because it's concatenating the already set `$PATH` string with `$HOME/bin:` right? But if `etc/profile` and `~/.profile` are the only files setting `PATH` where is `$PATH` coming from in that line of code if it's not defined in `/etc/profile`?

Can someone experienced please give a broad and detailed explanation of the `PATH` variable? Thanks!

Comment: sorry, it took years to answer. Cross-posting from https://stackoverflow.com/a/77740722/847349 : 

indeed, finding out where some part is defined requires too much effort.

Thus, I’ve codified the heuristics into a tool:

https://github.com/d-led/pathdebug

`pathdebug PATH` and you'll get the sources, and whether the directories exist or are duplicates

Answer (score 37):

There are many places where `PATH` can be set.

The `login` program sets it to a default value. How this default value is configured is system-dependent. On most non-embedded Linux systems, it's taken from [`/etc/login.defs`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/login.defs), with different values for root and for other users. Consult the `login(1)` manual on your system to find out what it does.

On systems using [PAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module), specifically the [`pam_env`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_env) module, environment variables can be set in the system-wide file `/etc/environment` and the per-user file `~/.pam_environment`.

Then most ways to log in (but not cron jobs) execute a [login shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell/46856#46856) which reads system-wide and per-user configuration files. These files can modify the value of `PATH`, typically to add entries but sometimes in other ways. Which files are read depend on what the login shell is. Bourne/POSIX-style shells read `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile`. Bash reads `/etc/profile`, but for the per-user file it only reads the first existing file among `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login` and `~/.profile`. Zsh reads `/etc/zshenv`, `~/.zshenv`, `/etc/zprofile`, `~/.zprofile`, `/etc/zlogin` and `~/.zlogin`. Many GUI sessions arrange to load `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile`, but this depends on the display manager, on the desktop environment or other session startup script, and how each distribution has set these up.

Answer (score 7):

The initial PATH variable is usually set in `/etc/profile`
Sometimes a sys admin will also put PATH variables to source in `/etc/profile.d`

These are the system PATH vars that everyone who logs in inherits by default (unless over-ridden locally). This usually sets obvious paths, like `/usr/bin`, although at my job we use `/opt` and a few custom locations extensively, so those are set there as well.

On a per-user login basis accounts, PATH may also be defined in `~/.profile`. That might define things that not all users have access to; maybe department heads can run binaries from `/opt` but other users aren't bothered with those binaries. Users can modify that file themselves, too, and the nice thing about `.profile` is that it is not shell-specific; if you login, the PATH set there gets sourced.

For shell-specific logins, PATH may be defined in `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc`, or `.cshrc`, or similar. Users can set PATH here if they want specific paths for specific shells, or if they just happen to maintain all their personal preferences there.

In summary: /etc/profile and /etc/profile.d are traditionally cascading settings; they get inherited and usually are added to in personal dot-files (although a user could choose to override them instead). Personal dot-files are usually set by a user.

Of course, a shell has environment variables, too, so a local environment variable can also add or override default PATH in any of the configuration files.

Comment: I've just checked all of those files which you mentioned, ~/.bash_profile and .cshrc do not exist however. The 3 script files in the /etc/profile.d dir: appmenu-qt5.sh, bash_completion.sh & vte.sh do not set the PATH variable either. What do you mean with "a shell has environment variables too" is the default PATH set in the binary /bin/bash program? When I terminal echo $PATH I get: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
 but I don't have an idea where that all is being set really.

Comment: I think I somewhat misread your question, I thought you were asking for all the locations PATH could be set, but I think you are more interested in where PATH is *initially* set. For that, look at `/etc/bashrc`. This determines how BASH is launched, which should include all  initial environment variables. On my system, `/etc/bashrc` reads from `/etc/profile.d` but it sounds like you only have 3 files in `/etc/profile.d` so your distro may be doing it differently.

Comment: I basically want to know the ins and outs of it. I wish Ken Thompson was my father :)

Comment: You'll get there. Believe me, after you use this stuff on a daily basis for a while, it all starts to sink in, and as long as you keep asking "why?" and reading docs for the answers, you do eventually learn a lot!

Comment: In Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon be sure to check /etc/profile.d/jdk_home.sh I renamed this file to jdk_home.sh.old and now my path does not keep getting overridden and I can call java -version and see Java 9 as expected. Even though I correctly selected Java 9 in update-aternatives --config java this jdk_home.sh file kept overriding the $PATH

Answer (score 5):

To add to the other answers:

`bash` will set `PATH` to a hard-coded default value if it's not set in the environment. On an Ubuntu Server 16.04.2 machine, I get:

```
$ env -i bash -c 'echo $PATH'
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:.
```

We can check that this value is indeed hard-coded, and not read from the environment or some file, using the `strings` utility:

```
$ strings /bin/bash | grep /usr/sbin
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:.
```

However, I get a different result on my Arch Linux machine:

```
$ env -i bash -c 'echo $PATH'
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
```

So, it looks like this default is chosen at the time the `bash` binary was built, which depends on the OS / distribution in use.

Answer (score 2):

Stuff, that I dont see:

- [X stuff](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281858/difference-between-xinitrc-xsession-and-xsessionrc)
- [Masterfiles](http://www.linfo.org/etc_skel.html) from where `.profile` etc are copied over on account creation
- [pam_env](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_env)
- A recent thread on [Debian](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/linux.debian.user/GqZqYG0SVdA%5B1-25%5D), where this is discussed in some detail.

As for Ken Thompson you may be surprised at his: ["Views on Linux"](http://genius.cat-v.org/ken-thompson/interviews/unix-and-beyond).

Answer (score 0):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/705912/where-is-my-path-variable-being-set

^^ This helped me. Try grepping 'PATH=' or 'export PATH=' instead of the actual directory to see where it is being set

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/421143)