# Difference between .xinitrc, .xsession and .xsessionrc

Tags: x11, login, startx, xinit

I found three configuration files.

1. `.xinitrc`
2. `.xsession`
3. `.xsessionrc`

I know that the first one is for using `startx` and the second and third are used when using a display manager. But what is the difference between the last two?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

`~/.xinitrc` is executed by [`xinit`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xinit), which is usually invoked via `startx`. This program is executed after logging in: first you log in on a text console, then you start the GUI with `startx`. The role of `.xinitrc` is to start the GUI part of the session, typically by setting some GUI-related settings such as key bindings (with `xmodmap` or `xkbcomp`), X resources (with `xrdb`), etc., and to launch a session manager or a window manager (possibly as part of a desktop environment).

`~/.xsession` is executed when you log in in graphical mode (on a [display manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager_(program_type))) and the display manager invokes the “custom” session type. (With the historical display manager xdm, `.xsession` is always executed, but with modern display managers that give the user a choice of session type, you usually need to pick “custom” for `.xsession` to run.) Its role is both to set login-time parameters (such as environment variables) and to start the GUI session. A typical `.xsession` is

```
#!/bin/sh
. ~/.profile
. ~/.xinitrc
```

`~/.xsessionrc` is executed on Debian (and derivatives such as Ubuntu, Linux Mint, etc.) by the X startup scripts on a GUI login, for all session types and (I think) from all display managers. It's also executed from `startx` if the user doesn't have a `.xinitrc`, because in that case `startx` falls back on the same session startup scripts that are used for GUI login. It's executed relatively early, after loading resources but before starting any program such as a key agent, a D-Bus daemon, etc. It typically sets variables that can be used by later startup scripts. It doesn't have any official documentation that I know of, you have to dig into the source to see what works.

`.xinitrc` and `.xsession` are historical features of the X11 Window system so they should be available and have a similar behavior on all Unix systems. On the other hand, `.xsessionrc` is a Debian feature and distributions that are not based on Debian don't have it unless they've implemented something similar.

`.xprofile` is very similar to `.xsessionrc`, but it's part of the [session startup script some display managers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xprofile) including GDM (the GNOME display manager) and lightdm, but not others such as xdm and kdm.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn’t aware that `~/.xsessionrc` is Debian-specific. It seems to be only briefly mentioned in [Debian manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch07.en.html#_customizing_the_x_session_new_method).

Comment: According to this [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xprofile) from [arch wiki](https://www.archlinux.org/), `.xprofile` is not only sourced by `GDM`

Comment: NB (copied from `man startx`): "Note that in the Debian system, what many people traditionally put in the .xinitrc file should go in .xsession instead; this permits the same X environment to be presented whether startx, xdm, or xinit is used to start the X session.  All discussion of the .xinitrc file in the xinit(1) manual page applies equally well to .xsession." I say this because the very existance of `~/.xinitrc` "breaks" [the Debian Alternatives System](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives)'s `x-session-manager` [link](https://wiki.debian.org/Xsession). HTH.

Comment: @jaimet I have a `.xinitrc` and I've never had a problem on Debian. But of course that could be because I specifically wrote my configuration to be portable. What goes wrong when `.xinitrc` exists?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' From my testing today, I find that as soon as `~/.xinitrc` exists, debian stops using `x-session-manager`/`x-window-manager` from the alternatives system. A few moments ago, I also found [head_on_a_stick's post from Feb 2020](https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?p=716295#p716295): "If ~/.xinitrc is present then the alternatives system is not consulted. Whatever is listed in ~/.xinitrc will be run regardless of what is selected as the x-{session,window}-manager alternative.". HTH (et merci bcp pour tout ce que vous m'avez enseigné !)

Comment: @jaimet That's just how `xinitrc` works: it describes your X session. That's not specific to Debian.

Answer (score 9):

According to another discussion, *[startx + ~/.xsession and no ~/.xinitrc, results in reduced functionality (xfce4, sid)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160806015248/http://www.eenyhelp.com/answer/startx-plus-xsession-no-xinitrc-results-reduced-functionality-xfce4-sid-help-213339652.html?page=3)*

> Firstly: `.xsessionrc` is for holding ***global environment*** variables.
>   The emphasis is mine.
>
> Secondly: `40x11-common_xsessionrc` in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d` is sourced
>   before `50x11-common_determine-startup`. So `.xsessionrc` is read before
>   `.xsession` and any environment variables set will become available to
>   applications run by the commands in `.xsession`.

Further reading:

- [Xsession - initialize X session](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man5/Xsession.5.html)
- [Understanding *NIX Login Scripts](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-nix-login-scripts/)

Comment: .xsessionrc can be used to startup apps too  -which is kind of contrary to the "global var" line. God It's a complicated mess.

Comment: @RichieHH Seconded: the [debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Xsession#User_configuration) explicitly adds `.`'ing (dot'ing) other posix shell config files and directly running X client programs. HTH.