# handling multiple window managers, multiple .xsessionrc files?

Tags: configuration, window-manager, gnome-shell, xmonad

I have just installed xmonad on my laptop with Debian jessie, and like it so far... I have previously used the default gnome-shell desktop *(/window?)* -manager, and still want to keep it 100% intact while I'm learning how to use xmonad.

Many xmonad tutorials talk about modifying the .xsessionrc file to add for example wallpapers, and so on http://beginners-guide-to-xmonad.readthedocs.io/wallpaper.html. However, I'm guessing that messing with the .xsessionrc file will also affect gnome-shell...

**Is it somehow possible to have multiple .xsessionrc files, such that I can have one for xmonad and one for gnome-shell?..** *or is there perhaps a better solution to this problem?*

I wish to keep the gnome-shell session as it is, and I also wish to keep the default display manager for login.

Comment: You could possibly have two files, one called `.xsessionrc.xmonad` and `.xsessionrc.gnome`, and just `cp` whichever one you need before started the X server. `cp .xsessionrc.xmonad .xsessionrc`

Answer (score 2):

`.xsessionrc` is executed for all session types. The session type is available in the variable `STARTUP` (for most session types), so you can put conditional statements in your `.xsessionrc`:

```
case "$STARTUP" in
  xmonad-session) …;;
  gnome-session) …;;
esac
```

The X session startup scripts are documented in [`Xsession(5)`](https://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=Xsession&sektion=5). You may need to read the code in `/etc/X11/Xsession` and `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/*` for more details.

Note that `.xsessionrc` is specific to Debian and derivatives. See [Difference between .xinitrc, .xsession and .xsessionrc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281858/difference-between-xinitrc-xsession-and-xsessionrc) for a discussion of standard X session files. The standard file `.xsession` only applies if you select “custom session” in the display manager when logging in, and `.xinitrc` only applies if you run `startx` (or `xinit`) after logging in in text mode.