# startx doesn't read xinitrc and Xprofile config files

Tags: x11, gnome, keyboard-layout, i3, startx

It happened after I have uninstalled GNOME on Fedora and switched completely to i3.

I use `.xinitrc` for setting wallpaper (what contains `exec i3` line as well), and `.Xprofile` for setting keyboard layouts using `setxbmap`.

The user login manager is gone along with the GNOME desktop environment, so I have to login in the TTY and manually type `startx` in order `i3` to start *without* displaying my wallpaper (as it used to) and without setting my keyboard layouts.

Comment: try to start X with `xinit` instead of `startx`

Comment: Thanks, tried, it doesn't work. Still no wallpaper and layouts loaded :)

Comment: I had a similar experience, and found this [description of the different X configuration files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/281923) to be helpful.