# URxvt font size is different at startup

Tags: xorg, i3, rxvt

I start a few urxvt terminals from my i3 config whenever I start a new i3 session. However, if I ever run `xrdb ~/.Xresources` to reload my urxvt config and then start another terminal, it's font size is much smaller than that of the terminals started from the i3 config. [image: i3 with different font sizes]

I know that both instances are reading ~/.Xresources because that's where I set the colorscheme. I came across a total hack with `xrandr --dpi 196` while searching, and it does actually make the font sizes the same, but the status bar fonts become very large as a result.

I've also tried adding `exec "xrdb ~/.Xresources"` to the i3 config before starting the terminals at startup, but it doesn't help - the startup terminals are the same, and as soon as I start a new terminal, it has a very small font size. I'm guessing the screen resolution is determined differently at startup than it is later, but I'm not sure how to go about debugging this.

My i3 config and `~/.Xresources` are linked [here](https://pastebin.com/QyM1Qwj3).

Answer (score 0):

To automatically run this command, I have

```
userressources=$HOME/.Xresources
if [-f $userressources]
then
  xrdb -merge $userressources
fi
```

in the file `.xprofile`.

See also [How to load ~/.Xresources when starting X?](https://superuser.com/questions/718727/how-to-load-xresources-when-starting-x.)

From [Difference between .xinitrc, .xsession and .xsessionrc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281858/difference-between-xinitrc-xsession-and-xsessionrc) it seems that the file you should to put that in depends on your login manager. It's probably that I'm using LightDM.