# what might be defining the $PATH variable?

Tags: bash, bashrc

I'm currently exploring and experimenting with my linux just for fun and educational purposes.

I have deleted the content of the `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `/etc/profile` and I don't have any configuration in the home directory for both root and local users, I also perform a reboot.

However when i run `printenv PATH` the values of the path was still there which is:

```
$PATH=usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games
```

what might be defining the $PATH?

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention that I'm using Kali linux.

I've found one of the culprit is in the `/etc/profile.d/kali.sh` as mentioned by a guy named flyingdrifter in the comment section of this thread ->
 [Complete view of where the PATH variable is set in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227989/complete-view-of-where-the-path-variable-is-set-in-bash)
(although his distribution is LinuxMint).

Now the $PATH variable has been reduced to

```
$PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games
```

which means that there are probably one last file that setting the PATH variable.

Comment: I missed the part where you didn't find any shell init files in the users homes but there are many other ways where the PATH environment variable can be set. I strongly suggest that you do more research into this to develop a better understanding before you delete files in `/etc` and shell init files in user's homes. A good place to start is the question in Wildcard's comment above.

Comment: @NasirRiley yeah, I found one of the culprit.. but I think there's one last file

Comment: If this is a vm, be sure to take snapshots before altering things in `/etc`.

Answer (score 0):

1. On most distributions there is something like (check your `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `/etc/profile` for code like this)

   ```
   for file in /etc/profile.d/*.sh ; do . $file ; done
   ```
2. There is PAM module called `pam_env` ([man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_env)), which by default sets the environment variables given in `/etc/environment`.

Comment: Those are specifically the files that the OP said that they cleared out.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `/etc/login.defs` and the `/etc/environment` as well.

More here:
[Complete view of where the PATH variable is set in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227989/complete-view-of-where-the-path-variable-is-set-in-bash)

Comment: my ```/etc/environment ``` doensn't have anything in it.. the ```/etc/login.def ```has some text.. I tried commenting out/deleting this line

``` 
ENV_SUPATH PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
ENV_PATH PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```
but it still have the path value