# What is the difference between using /bin/hdfs and hdfs?

Tags: bash

Some scripts in my company call some functions like `hdfs`, or `cat`, `echo`, etc.

Sometimes, it's done via:

```
echo "something"
```

And other times via:

```
/usr/bin/echo "something"
```

If any, what is the difference between these two ways of using a command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell your login session where to look for executables using an environment variable named `PATH`, a list of directories separated by a colon.

It has some value [set by default](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227989/complete-view-of-where-the-path-variable-is-set-in-bash), something like this:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

You can also [add your own directories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path), e.g.:

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

---

All executables in these directories can be executed directly from anywhere using only its name. `echo` is in one of these directories. To find out where exactly run:

```
$ which echo
/bin/echo
```

Using a full path to an executable can be useful in some cases, as the `PATH` variable may be different depending on the environment. This can cause problems e.g. when calling scripts via cron.