# "Run dialog" BOX is not recognizing custom commands

Tags: linux, environment-variables, path, gnome-terminal, run-dialog

I completely switched to linux a week ago, I modified my windows to run commands on "Execute" box (<kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) and thats VERY handy, for such things like open folders in specific locations, same as terminals or do some other actions like change some configurations in a bit by writing just a word, anyways.

In order to do the same on linux, I discovered the **"RUN DIALOG" box**, which looks pretty handy too.

#### What I tried:

Change my .bashrc file to include my path to `~/.custom-scripts`. With that done, I can perfectly run the commands from a normal terminal.

Not happens the same when I run the commands from the **"run dialog" box**, where it says `failed to execute child process "dev" (no such file or directory)` where "dev" is the bash file to open all the software I use while developing, opened in a specific location with some config.

I've been trying to change my `~/.profile` file to let **"run dialog" box** know where my scripts are, because is where that terminal listen for enviroment variables, but NOTHING works.

#### Most detailed steps:

- Add `export PATH="$PATH:~/.custom-scripts"` into my `~/.bashrc` file.

  That let me execute my scripts from the normal terminal.
- Add `export PATH="$PATH:~/.custom-scripts"` or `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.custom-scripts"` or `export PATH="$PATH:/home/user/.custom-scripts"` into my `~/.profile` file.

  That does not work.

After all the commands I trying by running `source .profile` and `source .bashrc`, even rebooting but none work for **"run dialog" box**.

[image: Run dialog box]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @vilinkameni How can I run commands on dialog box, either specifying a PATH folder to let "RUN DIALOG" know where are my files or doing it from any other way that I may don't know.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the actual question from your comment. As for the question, I don't know what is the "run dialog" to which you refer as I don't use desktop environments, but if that GUI program uses `PATH` in any way, this question has answers which might help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227989/complete-view-of-where-the-path-variable-is-set-in-bash