# How to run sh without reading ~/.profile?

Tags: shell, dash

With `bash`, for example, one can pass the `--norc --noprofile` flags to prevent the reading of shell initialization files.

What's the equivalent for `sh`?

If there isn't one for `sh`, is there at least one for `dash`?

(I've tried hacks based on temporarily unsetting `HOME`, but they seem to be too fragile for production work.)

Comment: I assume you mean an instance of a login shell; non-login shells read no files by default (so `--norc` wouldn't be needed, and is in fact ignored by `bash` when started with the name `sh`). I don't think there is anyway to prevent a login shell from sourcing `/etc/profile`, though.

Comment: Read your shell's man page, section `Invocation`. How does it detect that it is a non-interactive shell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sh` only loads `.profile` [if it's a login shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell/46856#46856), i.e. if it's invoked with argument 0 starting with `-`. So if you don't want `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` to be read, invoke the shell with the default argument 0 (the name of the executable).

If something is executing the shell as a login shell, you don't have control over arguments. If not, the shell isn't a login shell.

Apart from the files that are loaded if the shell is a login shell, there's one other file that some `sh` implementations load: the file indicated in the `ENV` environment variable. If you're invoking a shell and don't want to load any file, make sure that `ENV` is unset.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like it. You can find the code at the link below. Seems there are no flags to control this behaviour.

http://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/dash/dash.git/tree/src/main.c#n147

Comment: A useful link is indeed http://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/dash/dash.git/tree/src/options.c , and it shows that xargv[0] *is checked* for the starting hyphen.