# Is it possible for there to be a login shell that's not interactive?

Tags: bash, login, startup, bashrc

In interpreting [this flowchart](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/)

[image]

I found that in man bash:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.

That states that **interactive login** shells read `/etc/profile` (without --noprofile)

Also, **non-interactive** shells with the option `--login` read `/etc/profile`

That seems to leave some possible **login** shells (in which the `$0` starts with a `-`) that being **non-interactive** (run an script, maybe as simple as `date`) may not read (source) `/etc/profile`.

To confirm or deny this idea:

First I tried to use `su -l -`, which starts a login shell with a `-` as the first character but I fail to make it non-interactive (and be able to present the tests to probe it).

Calling something like

```
$ bash -c 'date' -bash
```

Doesn't report to be an login shell (even if the first character is a `-`).

> Try this to reveal the detail:
>
> ```
>    $ bash -c 'echo "$0 $- ||$(shopt -p login_shell)||";date' -bash
>       -bash hBc ||shopt -u login_shell||
>       Fri Aug 19 06:32:31 EDT 2016
> ```
>
> The `$0` has a `-` as the first character, there is no `i` (interactive) in the value of `$-` but it is not reported as a `login_shell` (the -u). In this case, /etc/profile was not read, but I am not sure this is the right test.

---

There is also the mention of "rare non-interactive login shells" [in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46856/184899) without being specific enough for this question.

---

The [conclusion of this guy](https://tanguy.ortolo.eu/blog/article25/shrc) is that `/etc/profile` is always read.

Read the summary table: both interactive and non-interactive login shells read `/etc/profile`

---

And, if [the examples from this page](https://airbladesoftware.com/notes/bash-startup-files/) are correct:

```
Some examples

$ su bob                   # interactive non-login shell
$ su - bob                 # interactive login shell
$ exec su - bob            # interactive login shell
$ exec su - bob -c 'env'   # non-interactive login shell
$ ssh bob@example.com      # interactive login shell, `~/.profile`
$ ssh bob@example.com env  # non-interactive non-login shell, `~/.bashrc`
```

The test of `exec su - bob -c 'env'` reports that `/etc/profile` was read.

---

In short:

Is it possible to have a **non-interactive login** shell (not called with --login or -l)?

And if true, is it reading the `/etc/profile` file?

If the above is true we have to conclude that **ALL** login shells [interactive (or not)] read /etc/profile (with no `--noprofile` option).

Note: to detect that /etc/profile is being read, just add at the very beginning of the file this command:

```
echo "'/etc/profile' is being read"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-interactive login shell is unusual, but possible. If you start the shell with the zeroth argument (which is normally the name of the executable) set to a string beginning with a `-`, it's a login shell, whether it's interactive or not.

```
$ ln -s /bin/bash ./-bash
$ echo 'shopt -p login_shell; echo $-' | HOME=/none PATH=.:$PATH -bash
shopt -s login_shell
hB
```

Your attempt `bash -c date -bash` didn't work because that doesn't tell the shell to be a login shell: the zeroth argument is `bash`, not `-bash`. After bash has started, it sets the variable `$0` to `-bash` instead of the zeroth argument, but the zeroth argument is what matters.

You can run a noninteractive login shell with `su -l` or `su -`, but you need to arrange for standard input not to be a terminal while still being able to be authorized (without having to type a password, or arranging for your password to be at the start of the input). It may be easier with sudo: run `sudo true` to get a presence credential, then while the credential is still valid run `echo 'shopt -p login_shell; echo $-' | sudo -i`.

See also [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell)

Answer (score 4):

I've seen graphical login environments that do:

```
exec "$SHELL" -l -c 'exec start-window-or-session-manager'
```

or the equivalent of:

```
exec -a "-$SHELL" "$SHELL" <<EOF
exec start-window-or-session-manager
EOF
```

So that the session initialisation file (like `~/.profile` for Bourne-like shells (and the corresponding ones in `/etc` for some)) be read and applied.

The first one doesn't work with all shells. `-l` is supported by a great number of shells, but not all, and on some, like `csh`/`tcsh`, can't be used with `-c`. The first character of `argv[0]` being `-` is understood by all shells though, as that's what `login` uses to tell the shells they are login shells.

In the second case, the stdin of that shell is something other than a `tty` device (`<<` is implemented by a temporary regular file, or a pipe depending on the shell), so the shell is not interactive (the definition of interactive being when a human interacts with it).

Comment: The first one is using the `--login` option. For the second one, if I do `exec -a "-bash" "bash" <<<"shopt -p login_shell; echo $0 $-"` I get (encoded in C qoutes) `$'/etc/profile read\nshopt -s login_shell\nbash himBH'` so, it is login but it is interactive. We need *login and non-interactive*. What is it that I am missing?

Comment: @sorontar, with `<<<"$-"`, that `$-` is expanded by the calling shell because of the double quotes. The called shell is not interactive because its stdin is not a tty.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are correct, Sir. However, correcting the mistake, we can do this:`exec -a "-bash" "bash" <<\EOF 
shopt -p login_shell; echo $0 $-
EOF` to get this confirmation: `$'/etc/profile read
stdin: is not a tty
shopt -s login_shell
-bash hB'` So, yes, a non-interactive login shell is possible, and it still read `/etc/profile`. Should we conclude that ALL login shells read `/etc/profile`?

Comment: ksh makes it pretty clear that it is a *non-interactive login shell*, try `exec -a "-ksh" "ksh" <<\EOF
echo $0; set -o
EOF`,  :).

Comment: @sorontar, I think you can expect most shell implementations to read their session initialisation file(s) when called as login shells. Which they are depends on the shell implementation and version. In the case of `bash`, the start-up file handling is pretty messed-up IMO, you'll find that some systems have patched it to have a more reasonable behaviour adding even more variation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, non-interactive login shells are possible

```
$ head -1 /etc/profile
echo PROFILE BEING READ

$ echo echo hello | su -
PROFILE BEING READ
stdin: is not a tty
hello

$
```

Comment: That is similar to this simplified: `su -c 'echo hello' -`. Which, to test what we need, should be written as: `su -c 'echo $0 $-; shopt -p login_shell' -` to get this confirming answer (encoded in C quotes): `$'/etc/profile read \n -su hBc \n shopt -s login_shell'`. That confirms that a login **non-interactive** shell was excuted and that, in the process, /etc/profile was read. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have a non-interactive login shell (not called with --login or -l)?

**YES.**

```
$ (exec -a '-' bash -c 'shopt -q login_shell && echo login shell')
```

However, note that `/etc/profile` would not be used for a non-interactve login shell unless the `--login` argument is given.

A common idiom that invokes a non-interactive login shell is:

```
$ su - someuser -c somecommand
```

But this suffers the fact that `/etc/profile` doesn't get executed.

It is possible to change this behavour but it involves customising the Bash source code at compile-time by uncommenting an option found in [config-top.h](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/config-top.h):

```
/* Define this to make non-interactive shells begun with argv[0][0] == '-'
run the startup files when not in posix mode. */
/* #define NON_INTERACTIVE_LOGIN_SHELLS */
```

When I [researched this `su` anomaly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336272/why-does-a-non-interactve-bash-login-shell-ignore-etc-profile-when-invoked-by-s), I found that other shells including `zsh` and `dash` don't have this discrepancy.