# Why does a non-interactve bash login shell ignore /etc/profile when invoked by su -?

Tags: bash, su

I am using `su` to start `tmux` as a specific user, like this:

```
$ su - someuser -c tmux
```

However, this results in an error message:

```
tmux: need UTF-8 locale (LC_CTYPE) but have ANSI_X3.4-1968
```

The error occurs because the `LANG` environment variable is not set. A new *login shell* normally sets this via `/etc/profile` but the invocation through `su` does not use `/etc/profile` even though the use of `su -` does request and appear to produce a login shell.

The user `someuser` that this does not work for has the `bash` shell. However, it works with other shells such as `dash` or `zsh`. An interactive `bash` login shell also works as expected.

**Why does `bash` ignore `/etc/profile` when when invoked *non-interactively* through `su -` ?**

My research (below) would indicate that the problem is that `bash`, in contrast to other shells, behaves differently when a login shell is requested with a leading hyphen in `$0` (what `su` does) versus its `-l` (or `--login`) command-line option.

---

### Research

*(this is somewhat verbose but I wanted to record my investigations)*

`man su` explains that the `-c` argument is used to

> Pass command to the shell with the -c option.

and the `-` argument

> Start the shell as a login shell with an environment similar to a real login

So `su - someuser -c cmd` should execute `cmd` in a login shell for `someuser` with an environment similar to a real login.

A test command is useful to demonstrate:

```
$ testcmd='shopt -q login_shell || echo -n non-; echo login shell $0 $LANG'
```

Trying this with `su` for login and non-login shells:

```
$ su - someuser -c "$testcmd"
login shell -bash
$ su someuser -c "$testcmd"
non-login shell bash en_GB.UTF-8
```

When a login shell is launched, the environment is not configured (`LANG` is not set because `/etc/profile` is not used). The environment is inherited from when a non-login shell is launched so the value of `LANG` is that from the launching shell, as clearing it beforehand demonstrates:

```
$ LANG= su someuser -c "$testcmd"
non-login shell bash
```

In the above examples, `someuser` has the `bash` shell. The same results are obtained with `sh` (which is just a symlink to `bash`). If `zsh` is used instead then things work as expected:

```
$ ztestcmd='[[ -o login ]] || echo -n non-; echo login shell $LANG'
$ LANG= su - someuser -s /bin/zsh -c "$ztestcmd"
Password: 
login shell -zsh en_GB.UTF-8
$ LANG= su someuser -s /bin/zsh -c "$ztestcmd"
Password: 
non-login shell zsh
su someuser -s /bin/zsh -c "$ztestcmd"
Password: 
non-login shell zsh en_GB.UTF-8
```

It also works with `dash`. So the issue would appear to be with `bash`. Delving into `bash`...

It works as expected if an interactive shell is launched:

```
$ su - someuser
$ LANG= shopt -q login_shell || echo -n non-; echo login shell $0 $LANG
login shell -bash en_GB.UTF-8
```

So interactive and non-interactive `bash` launched through `su` behave differently. What about launching `bash` directly?

```
$ LANG= bash -c "$testcmd"
non-login shell bash
$ LANG= bash -l -c "$testcmd"
login shell bash en_GB.UTF-8
```

That works as expected.

The GNU Bash Manual [states](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) that

> When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the `--login` option, it first reads and executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`

According to man `su`, its `-` option does not use `--login` but instead

> sets argv[0] of the shell to `-` in order to make the shell a login shell

Which can be proven:

```
$ su - someuser -c 'echo $0'
Password: 
-bash
```

We can test ourselves that a leading hyphen in `$0` gives a login shell:

```
$ (LANG= exec -a '-' bash -c "$testcmd")
login shell -
```

So **a leading hyphen in `$0`** produces a login shell but `bash` **does not execute `/etc/profile`** when invoked in this way which is inconsistent with the behaviour of its `-l` option and also with other shells such as `zsh` or `dash`. It's also inconsistent with its own behaviour when launched interactively:

```
$ (LANG= exec -a '-' bash)
$ shopt -q login_shell || echo -n non-; echo login shell $0 $LANG
login shell - en_GB.UTF-8
```

Unfortunately this isn't in conflct with the documentation excerpted above because that doesn't define the behaviour of a non-interactive login shell that was not launched with `-l`.

Comment: Try the more dependable `/etc/environment` (caveat: the surprising syntax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It does what it says on the tin.**

Recall the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html):

> When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the `--login` option, it first reads and executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`

It explains correctly that it reads and executes `/etc/profile` as an  **interactive login shell** or as a **non-interactive shell with the `--login` option**. It does not say that it does so as a non-interactive login shell indicated by `$0` beginning with a hyphen.

However, this behaviour is by design and it is something that can be changed at compile time by uncommenting a compile-time option found in [config-top.h](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/config-top.h):

```
/* Define this to make non-interactive shells begun with argv[0][0] == '-'
run the startup files when not in posix mode. */
/* #define NON_INTERACTIVE_LOGIN_SHELLS */
```

This does beg the question, however, why this behaviour was implemented when it isn't, *IMHO*, how one would reasonably expect it to work, especially when it isn't implemented like that in other shells.

That said, I don't think the [POSIX standard shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799) defines *login shell* so I guess it's open to interpretation.

Here is a workaround to the original problem that works with `bash`:

```
$ su - someuser -c 'bash -l -c tmux'
```