# .shinit vs. .shrc

Tags: shell

When logging in to a Linux/Unix system via the old Bourne shell (`sh`), we have the `.profile` file to customize our environment for us.  Some sources also reference either a `.shinit` file or a `.shrc` file.  When is it appropriate to use one of these and what's the difference between them?

Answer (score 9):

`.profile` is only run when a **login** shell is started. If you want a script to run for every shell, you set the `ENV` environment variable to the name of this shell, and the shell will execute it. You can name this file whatever you want, `.shinit` and `.shrc` are common names.

You would use this script to set options that need to be set in each shell instance, because they're not automatically inherited as part of the environment.

Note that `bash` doesn't require this environment variable, it will load `.bashrc` by default.

See also [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell/38176)

Comment: While this information is accurate, it does not explain the use of nor the difference between the `.shinit` and `.shrc` files.

Comment: There is no difference. You can use any name you want, you just put it in the `ENV` variable.