# What is the exact difference between a .login and .cshrc file?

Tags: login, csh

I have searched the internet and websites say that we can edit both the file as per our needs and first `.cshrc` file is executed and then the `.login` file.

That is fine but what is the exact difference between the two. Please tell in easy words. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The manual describes what files (t)csh loads when it starts. (T)csh always reads `.cshrc`. `.login` is only read if the shell is a login shell, i.e. the first program after logging in. When you type your username and password on a text console, or when you use SSH to log into a remote machine, you get a login shell and `.login` is read. When you open a terminal in a GUI session, or when a shell runs a script, this isn't a login shell and only `.cshrc` is read. For more information, see [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell) (which discusses sh-style shells, not csh; the principle is the same but the file names are different and the fact that `.cshrc` is loaded in scripts is a csh specificity).

`.login` is the place to define things that should be done at the start of the session, such as setting environment variables. `.cshrc` is the place to set shell parameters such as aliases, key bindings, etc. Beware that (t)csh loads `.cshrc` even in scripts.

Note that `.login` is not executed when you log in at a graphical prompt (unless the GUI session is based on a csh script, but I've never seen that, it would be extremely unusual). What scripts are executed on a graphical login varies but `.profile` (the sh equivalent of `.login`) is very common.

Csh was a better interactive shell than others in the 1980s but it hasn't really evolved since the 1990s and has been overtaken by zsh and bash. Don't learn csh now, you're at least 20 years out of date. Bash is pre-installed on virtually all systems that have csh and many more, and zsh is if not pre-installed then at least available as a package.