# /etc/zprofile or /etc/zsh/zprofile

Tags: shell, zsh, login

Zsh manual says that /etc/zprofile is sourced during login, but it's not being sourced in my system. But if I add `source /etc/zprofile` to /etc/zsh/zprofile, the required behaviour is achieved. Initially /etc/zsh/profile contained `source /etc/profile`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you really using a [login shell](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell)?

Comment: Yes, I'm on a tty.

Comment: Can you make the test with : `if [[ -o login ]]; then; print yes; else; print no; fi` ?

Comment: The command prints yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely what has happened is ZSH ships with default X (`/etc/zprofile`) and your vendor has changed that to Y (`/etc/zsh/profile`) without also correcting the documentation regarding X. In other words, take documentation about file paths with a grain of salt, especially where a modern relative of Procrustes has shoehorned ZSH into some file hierarchy standard or the other.

Sometimes with `strings` one can discover these fiddlings with file paths:

```
strings =zsh | grep profile
```

Or by tracing the system calls and seeing what files `zsh` touches e.g. on Linux via `strace` or `sysdig`:

```
strace -o grepme zsh -ic exit
fgrep profile grepme
```

Actually `zsh` is good at telling what files it is reading:

```
zsh -ixc exit 2>&1 | fgrep profile
```

Comment: You are right. Just checked the build files of my distro.