# Difference between systemd and terminal starting program

Tags: shell, permissions, systemd, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am curious as to what this difference is between programs that are; started with systemd when enabled through systemctl, vs those started by means of `/etc/rc.local` or through the CLI.

For example, I was recently using shairport-sync for the raspberry pi. Initially, I set shairport-sync to start by means of sudo systemctl enabled shairport-sync.

Later down the road I used a functionality within `shairport-sync` to run scripts prior and post to devices connecting.

To my surprise, the scripts when executed by `shairport-sync` did not `kill` `arecord` or `aplay`

However, when I would run the script via terminal the script executed and killed `arecord` and `aplay`.

To further confuse myself, I killed `shairport-sync` and started it via terminal to see the output of what was happening. When I did so the scripts functioned as I expected when the device connected and killed `arecord` and `aplay`. So, as a fix I disabled `shairport-sync` in `sysmtectl` and set it to run in `/etc/rc.local` as a quick fix. After a `reboot` it functioned as I expected.

This leads me to believe that there is some difference between a program run as apart of `systemd` and a program that runs when started via `/etc/rc.local` or the CLI.

Why does this happen? Is this because of different run levels? Some dark magic?

The script that is run when a device connects to `shairport-sync` is as follows: `shairportstart.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/sudo /bin/pkill arecord
if [ $(date +%H) -ge "18" -o $(date +%H) -le "7" ]; then
        /usr/bin/amixer set Speaker 40%
else
        /usr/bin/amixer set Speaker 100%
fi
/home/pi/shScripts/shairportfade.sh&

exit 0
```

Here is the fade script: `shairportfade.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/amixer set Speaker 30-
for (( i=0; i<30; i++))
do  
    /usr/bin/amixer set Speaker 1+
done
exit 0
```

The script that is run when a device disconnects to `shairport-sync` is as follows: `shairportend.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/amixer set Speaker 70%
/usr/bin/arecord -D plughw:1 -f dat | /usr/bin/aplay -D plughw:1 -f dat&
exit 0
```

I found the following error in the `/var/log/syslog` only when shairport-sync was initially run as apart of `systemd`. When `shairport-sync` was run from the CLI or `/etc/rc.local` there were no errors present.

```
Jan 24 00:38:45 raspberrypi shairport-sync[617]: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Please note, that the only difference is how `shairport-sync` is initially started, when devices connect or disconnect `shairport-sync` continues to run.

Comment: That `ps ... awk ... grep ...` stuff might be replaced by a simpler `pkill`

Comment: @thrig originally the line was much simpler but since it didn't work or so I thought I tried using other methods to kill the instance which still didn't work. Killing the process wasn't the issue per se, as it worked but only when run from a user login

Comment: can you show the listing of `/home/pi/shScripts/shairportfade.sh` ?

Comment: @MichaelD. i have added the fade script as well as the script that is execute when a device disconnects to shairport-sync

Comment: @BrettReinhard what's the problem with running the script from `rc.local`

Comment: @MichaelD. I am unsure if that is a proper way to handle such programs as I am still pretty new to linux and unsure of proper standards. Regardless, the way that `shairport-sync` is implemented most users enable `shairport-sync` by means of `sudo systemctl enable shairport-sync`. Since, I also raised an issue on the github page I felt it was my due diligence to find a fix for the issue with how it is installed by most users.

Comment: In my simplistic view of this world, if anything cannot kill a process, then it does not have rights to do so. As in you need `sudo` to kill someone else's process.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Variations of *"Why do things behave differently under systemd?"* are a frequently asked question.

Any time something runs from the CLI and not from systemd, there are a some broad categories of possibilities to account for differences.

1. *Different environment variables*. `systemd` documents the environment variables it passes in `man systemd.exec` in the section [Environment variables in spawned processes](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Environment%20variables%20in%20spawned%20processes). If you want to inspect the difference yourself, you can use `systemd-run /path/to/binary`, it will run your app in a transient scope, as it would be run by a systemd service. You'll get output like: `Running as unit: run-u160.service`. You can then `journalctl -u run-u160.service` to review the output. Modify your app to dump out the environment variables it receives and compare the CLI run to the systemd run. If the app isn't conveniently modified, you can just use `systemd-run env` to see the environment variables that would be passed and review the resulting journal logging for it. If you are trying to start an X11 GUI app, the [`DISPLAY` environment variable needs to be set](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/355177/20239). In that case, consider using your desktop environment's "autostart" feature instead of `systemd`.
2. *Resource restrictions*. See [`man systemd.resource-control`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html) for configuration values which could restrict resource consumption. Use `systemctl show your-unit-unit.service` to check the full configuration values affecting the service you attempting to start.
3. *Non-interactive shell*. Your `bash` CLI environment is an *interactive login shell*. It has sourced files like `.bashrc` that `systemd` has not. Besides setting environment variables, these scripts can do any number of other things, such as connecting an SSH agent so that SSH actions don't require a login. See also [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell)
4. *No TTY*. Your interactive session is connected to a TTY that some programs like `sudo` and `ssh` expect when prompting for passwords. See also [sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281742/sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified)
5. *Relative vs. Absolute Paths*. Relative binary work in the shell, but [as documented in `man systemd.service`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStart=), the first argument to `ExecStart=` must be an absolute path to a binary.
6. *Restricted command line syntax*. Shell CLIs support many metacharacters, while [`systemd` has a very restricted command line syntax](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines). Depending on your needs, you may be able to replicate Shell syntax with `systemd` by explicitly running your command through a shell: `ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/my/bash $(syntax) >/goes-here.txt'`

It's a feature that system runs your code in a consistent environment with resource controls. This helps with reproducible, stable results in the long run without overwhelming the hardware.

Comment: Also need to take into account MAC context (SELinux,...), capabilities, namespaces...

Comment: I believe the error that I seemed to encountered is somehow related to when `/etc/sudoers` gets loaded to the system. It is my understanding that when systemd starts a given program, such as `shairport-sync` sudo rules have not been loaded. Given that you suggested that system runs in a consistent environment and `shairport-sync` was run in that environment, it will require a password for using `sudo`. Where if it were run in `/etc/rc.local` sudoers would be loaded and not need the password

Comment: systemd system units run as root by default, so `sudo` would not be needed.

Comment: given that `shairport-sync` is a system unit. Say for example `shairport-sync` were to run some script named `deviceconnectionhandler` which would be in control of running the scripts that are executed when a device connects or disconnects. Would the scripts run by `deviceconnectionhandler` also have the root privilege and not need sudo?

Comment: Correct. Any sub process would inherit the ownership and privileges of the parent.

Comment: So the error that is happening is : `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`. Which to me begs the question when a script run as root uses `sudo` will it require a password input? Or is this error more specifically due to `no tty present`? Thank you for your patience in answering my questions.

Comment: @BrettReinhard Do not call `sudo` in a shell script better run `sudo shairportstart.sh` from terminal, since systemd is running the script as root, no need to sudo as root.

Comment: Normally using `sudo` with the `root` user doesn't prompt for a password, but something is clearly attempting to use a TTY and there is no TTY in the systemd context. Figure out what's trying to use a TTY and make it stop, or see if there's an option force a pseudo-tty allocation that you can script passing something to. Both `sudo` and `ssh` have pseudo-tty options.

Comment: I solved my issue multiple ways in my attempt to understand what was happening. Ultimately, what I ended up doing was changing my kill command to `/usr/bin/echo "mypassword" | /usr/bin/sudo /bin/pkill arecord`. Later on today, I will try removing the `sudo` and `echo` commands to my kill command and see if that yields the same results. My guess is that will work, as it seems that the error was caused by no password being sent with the `sudo` command. Thank you for the help in understanding as to why there is a difference between `systemd` and the CLI

Comment: One other difference, which may be obvious but which bit me today, is that systemd tries to track the status of a service and won't start it if it thinks it's already active, so it may not even launch an init.d script if it thinks the service is running. By contrast, init.d scripts are typically written to always check and try to start the service as appropriate.

Comment: @JoshKelley Thanks for the tip. That's not a difference between systemd and the CLI but between systemd and sysVinit init.d scripts.