# Starting systemd service inside systemd service causes deadlock

Tags: systemd

I have a systemd service (let's call it `first.service`) that calls a bash script.

In that bash script I first stop and then start another service with `systemctl` (e.g. `systemctl start another.service`.

I have noticed that when I execute my script in a shell- everything works correctly and `another.service` is being stopped and later started.

When I call `systemctl restart first.service` systemd stops the "`another.service`" properly, but hangs on starting it.

When I check result of `ps` it says that both systemctl calls are working, i.e. `systemctl restart first.service` and `systemctl start another.service`.

I use systemd 230

Is this known behaviour? How can I fix this?

Is there any better way to handle (re)starting systemd services from within the one service?

**EDIT**:
My `first.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=First service
#Before=local-fs.target apache2.service rsyslog.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/test.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My `another.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Test service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "while ( true  ) ; do { date ; echo 'It works!' ; sleep 10 ; } done"
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo stopping
systemctl stop another.service
echo "result of stop = $?"
echo starting
systemctl start another.service
echo "result of start = $?"
echo DONE
```

After hanging I get the following output from `ps`:

```
[piotr@/etc/systemd/system] $ ps -aux | grep systemctl
root      7801  0.0  0.0  27696  1336 pts/21   S+   16:06   0:00 systemctl restart first
root      7807  0.0  0.0  27696  1320 ?        S    16:06   0:00 systemctl start another.service
piotr     7915  0.0  0.0  15752   968 pts/22   S+   16:06   0:00 grep --color=auto systemctl
```

**EDIT2**:
I'm posting `systemctl status` from both services in the exact moment when in another console I called `systemctl restart first`.

I have also added checking return value in my bash script. Updated above.

`first.service`:

```
● first.service - First service
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/first.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: activating (start) since Wed 2017-04-19 16:34:43 CEST; 46s ago
Main PID: 12761 (test.sh)
CGroup: /system.slice/first.service
├─12761 /bin/bash /usr/bin/test.sh
└─12766 systemctl start another.service

Apr 19 16:34:43 piotr-ideapad systemd[1]: Starting First service...
Apr 19 16:34:43 piotr-ideapad test.sh[12761]: stopping
Apr 19 16:34:43 piotr-ideapad test.sh[12761]: result of stop = 0
Apr 19 16:34:43 piotr-ideapad test.sh[12761]: starting
```

`another.service`:

```
● another.service - Test service
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/another.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: activating (start) since Wed 2017-04-19 16:34:43 CEST; 1min 40s ago
Main PID: 12767 (bash)
CGroup: /system.slice/another.service
├─12767 /bin/bash -c while ( true   ) ; do { date ; echo 'It works!' ; sleep 10 ;  } done
└─13066 sleep 10

Apr 19 16:35:43 piotr-ideapad bash[12767]: Mi 19. Apr 16:35:43 CEST 2017
Apr 19 16:35:43 piotr-ideapad bash[12767]: It works!
Apr 19 16:35:53 piotr-ideapad bash[12767]: Mi 19. Apr 16:35:53 CEST 2017
Apr 19 16:35:53 piotr-ideapad bash[12767]: It works!
Apr 19 16:36:03 piotr-ideapad bash[12767]: Mi 19. Apr 16:36:03 CEST 2017
Apr 19 16:36:03 piotr-ideapad bash[12767]: It works!
Apr 19 16:36:13 piotr-ideapad bash[12767]: Mi 19. Apr 16:36:13 CEST 2017
Apr 19 16:36:13 piotr-ideapad bash[12767]: It works!
Apr 19 16:36:23 piotr-ideapad bash[12767]: Mi 19. Apr 16:36:23 CEST 2017
Apr 19 16:36:23 piotr-ideapad bash[12767]: It works!
```

**EDIT3**: After exchanging some comments I'll try to rephrase the problem.

Say that none of my processes listed above is enabled or started. When I call `systemctl status` on them - they are `loaded` but `inactive`.
Then I call `systemctl start first` and this terminal command does not finish. 
If I call `systemctl status` on those services I get that status of `Active:` for both of them is `activating (start)` but my execution of `systemctl start first` in the terminal still did not exit and it hangs indefinitely.

I think that both of those processes are queued and `systemctl start another` in my bash script waits for the `systemctl start first` to finish before it finishes by itself and here we get a deadlock.

Comment: It works to call `systemctl` within a systemd service. Post your systemd configuration and key parts of your scripts for further help. Also read [Difference between systemd and terminal starting program](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/339645/20239).

Comment: @MarkStosberg- I've added my service files. there are no changes to the `systemd.conf` (only not commented out line is `[Manager]`

Comment: What about the output from `journalctl` that may be related? (the systemd journal)

Comment: I'm not sure if journalctl gives us anything, but I added `systemctl status`. I hope this helps answer the question.

Comment: From your status output, it appears to be working. You'll have to carefully check the timestamps to confirm which output is from a manual run and which is from a systemd run. (Or, you could modify the string "It works!" between the manual run and the systemd run)

Comment: @MarkStosberg : Please take a look at my question again. I have added an edit where I rephrase my issue. Once it is resolved I'll try to shorten the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What appears to be a deadlock is actually the `Type=oneshot` directive working as advertised. The "hang" can be triggered by running your `another.service` directly:

```
systemctl start another
```

Once cancelled, one can review `journalctl` to find it wasn't "hung" at all, but running an infinite loop as expected.   In `man systemd.service`, we find the documentation for `Type=oneshot`:

> Behavior of oneshot is similar to simple; however, it is expected that the process has to exit before systemd starts follow-up units.

In other words, you have written an infinite loop and then instructed systemd to wait till it finishes before moving on.

You either need to use a different `Type=`, like `Type=simple`, or quit using an infinite loop for your main process.

Comment: I just tested it and it works perfectly with a type changed to simple. Thanks for this.