# Failure to start custom service using systemd

Tags: systemd, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Good morning,

We are trying to start a custom service on a Raspberry PIZero Wireless. The procedure we are using works on a PI3 under Ubuntu 14.04. The PiZero runs 2017-04-10-raspbian-jessie. I'll use the name CUSTOM_SERVICE below.

I tried different things without success. Querying the status of the service reports:

```
sudo systemctl status CUSTOM_SERVICE.service
● CUSTOM_SERVICE.service - Custom service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/CUSTOM_SERVICE.service; enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-04-26 14:44:40 UTC; 32s ago
  Process: 1516 ExecStart=/usr/local/etc/startCustomService (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 1516 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Apr 26 14:44:40 raspberrypi systemd[1]: CUSTOM_SERVICE.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Apr 26 14:44:40 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Unit CUSTOM_SERVICE.service entered failed state.
```

Using the command:

```
sudo ls -l /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*.service
```

output:

```
...
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 Apr 10 09:24 /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/avahi-daemon.service -> /lib/systemd/system/avahi-daemon.service
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Apr 26 13:53 /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/CUSTOM_SERVICE.service -> /etc/systemd/system/CUSTOM_SERVICE.service
...
```

The service unit file is defined as:

```
more /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/CUSTOM_SERVICE.service
[Unit]
Description=Custom service
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
RestartSec=60
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/local/etc/startCustomService

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

where */usr/local/etc/startCustomService* is defined as

```
more /usr/local/etc/startCustomService
#!/bin/sh
/usr/local/sbin/customService
```

As I said, the service is launched and running correctly under Ubuntu 14.04. Also note that the file */usr/local/etc/startCustomService* can be launched manually on PIZero.

Any suggestions?

Regards,
Daniel

Comment: Have you read [Difference between systemd and terminal starting program](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/339645/20239) and reviewed all the possible differences for a service to not run under systemd vs the shell?

Comment: Your service exited with code 203. You should refer to the documentation for your service to determine the meaning of this exit code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Looking at /var/log/syslog, I saw the error  `Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/local/etc/startCustomService: No such file or directory`. The actual error was related to DOS type line termination in the different files, most importantly the _startCustomService_ script.  - Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Try add working directory.

```
WorkingDirectory=/usr/local/etc/
```