# Running a binary as systemd service does not work

Tags: systemd

I have a go project and when I compile it I get your typical binary. If I call the binary directly from the command line with the adequate inputs, it runs perfectly well. I want to make this program part of the systemd ecosystem though and the following is my binary.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Run Go Service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/directory/
ExecStart=/path/to/directory/binary --config /full/path/to/service.conf
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I can start and stop the service using the usual call `sudo service application start`. I don't receive any error messages but when I check `journalctl -xe` it says the start failed but it gives no details as to why. If I run the exact same command through the command line and not through systemd, the application runs just fine. How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: `service` command is `initd` component. Try start service as `systemctl start application` and `systemctl status application` after it.

Comment: It gives out no error messages. But this program should have a server running and I can not connect to that ip:port so for all intents and purposes the service is still unreachable.

Comment: I'm by far no systemd expert, but I read a few articles recently, and it might be that you have tell systemd what kind of behaviour to expect from your application by using the `Type=` parameter in the unit file.

Comment: I have tried that to. My current version of the file has `Type=simple` (which is also the default if you don't add a type) but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: It's no need to set `Type=`. By default it has `simple` value and starts service from `ExecStart` field value. "No need" - I mean case from question.

Comment: Is your application an ordinary application or daemon? Service file looks like good, but no more info about your application.

Comment: It is basically a go binary that runs a server. So an ordinary application I'd say.

Comment: Both `journalctl` and `systemctl status` in fact *do* give details of what is going on, and this information needs to be [edit]ed into your question.

Comment: Please ready the the answer to the FAQ [Why do things behave differently under systemd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/339645/20239) and see if one of those cases applies.