# Unattended upgrades won’t use mailx when run by Systemd

Tags: systemd, sendmail, mailx, unattended-upgrades

I have setup `unattended-upgrades` on servers running Raspbian (`Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.4 (stretch)`). Version of Unattended-upgrades: `0.93.1+nmu1`

Updates work, but I am having problems with the email reporting.
I want to use `mailx` for sending reports. If I run the update with command `unattended-upgrade -v -d` the report gets sent and it uses the email configuration I have in `/root/.mailrc`.

When `unattended upgrades` are run by the Systemd timer (`apt-daily-upgrade.timer`), however, it won’t use `mailx`.

If `sendmail` is present it is used to send the mail. In that case, the mail gets sent, but the sender is `root@hostname` and the messages get flagged as spam.

If there is no `sendmail` I see this error in journal of `apt-daily-upgrade`:

```
Cannot start "/usr/sbin/sendmail": executable not found (adjust *sendmail* variable)
```

I cannot understand why different mail programs gets used depending on how the task was started.

I have tried to edit `unattended-upgrades` Python program to force it use `mailx`:

```
if os.path.exists(SENDMAIL_BINARY):
        ret = _send_mail_using_sendmail(from_email, to_email, subject, body)
    elif os.path.exists(MAIL_BINARY):
        ret = _send_mail_using_mailx(from_email, to_email, subject, body
```

I changed the variable `SENDMAIL_BINARY` to point to a non-existing path so it would forced to use `mailx`. This too worked when invoked `unattended-upgrades` manually but failed when it was run by Systemd. (And the above error about trying to use `sendmail` still gets logged.)

How can I force `unattended upgrades` to use `mailx` even when is run automatically by systemd and what is causing the difference in Mail program that gets used?

EDIT:

System unit file that runs Unattended upgrades:

```
[Unit]
Description=Daily apt upgrade and clean activities
Documentation=man:apt(8)
ConditionACPower=true
After=apt-daily.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily install
KillMode=process
TimeoutStopSec=900
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a variation of the FAQ [Why do things work differently under systemd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/339645/20239).

One of the benefits of `systemd` is that it provides a consistent execution environment. To error on the side of security and simplicity, the environment variables set are minimal.

The related docs on the [`systemd` execution environment](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) detail what's set.

You mentioned that your configuration was in the `root` home directory. `man mailx` confirms It is looking in `~/.mailrc`, as opposed to the fixed path `/root/.mailrc`.

The `systemd` docs clarify that the `$HOME` variable is only set when the `User=` directive is used. You did not share your `systemd` service file, but I presume since you are running the task as root you did not use the `User=` directive.  So that could explain part of your issue.

It also appears that a path you want may not be set by your `$PATH` environment variable when run by `systemd`.  You can confirm this by replacing the `ExecStart=` line in your service with:

```
 ExecStart=/bin/echo "My path is $PATH"
```

If the `mailx` path is not listed, you can explicitly set with an `Environment=` directive.

If this explicit tips don't solve your issue, be sure to check out the FAQ linked above for more possibilities.

Comment: I ended up solving my problem by running `unattended-upgares` from Crontab instead of Systemd as that worked right away without any issues. But I belive I tips of this answer explain my issues when using Systemd. If I have time I might try them in practice later.

Answer (score 2):

I use `msmtp` and `bsd-mailx` on Ubuntu 18.04 to allow `unattended-upgrades` to email me on updates. I think I ran into the same problem as you. I configured `msmtp` and I could send email using `mailx` from the command line. `unattended-upgrades` would also send me an email if I ran it myself from the command line, but if `unattended-upgrades` would run automatically then I would receive no email. Looking in the logs of `/var/log/msmtp/msmtp.log` I saw:

```
<DATE> host=<MY_SMTP_HOST> tls=on auth=on user=<MY_STMP_USERNAME> from=<MY_EMAIL_ADDRESS> recipients=<MY_EMAIL_ADDRESS> smtpstatus=550 smtpmsg='550 5.2.0 Mail format error: No domain in From header [1633]' errormsg='the server did not accept the mail' exitcode=EX_UNAVAILABLE
```

So there is a problem setting the `From header`. Diving into this it appears that the `from` email address used by `unattended-upgrades` defaults to `root`, but you can define this yourself in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` by adding `Unattended-Upgrade::Sender "<EMAIL_ADDRESS>";`. This fixed it for me.