# How to start git-daemon at boot?

Tags: systemd, git, start-stop-daemon

I've created scripts to control starting, stopping, etc. of my git-daemon on Fedora28.  I'm now attempting to link these scripts to a systemd service so git-daemon will be available after reboot.

The primary script (gitT) is...

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
  'start')
    echo "Starting git-daemon"
    /home/git/scripts/start.sh >> /home/git/gitT.log
    ;;
  'stop')
    echo "Stopping git-daemon"
    /home/git/scripts/stop.sh >> /home/git/gitT.log
    ;;
  'restart')
    echo "Bouncing git-daemon"
    /home/git/scripts/bounce.sh >> /home/git/gitT.log
    ;;
  'status')
    echo "Status of git-daemon"
    /home/git/scripts/status.sh
    ;;
  *)
    echo "`basename $0`: usage: `basename $0` { stop | start | restart | status }"
    ;;
esac
```

Secondary scripts are...

start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# --------------------------
echo "---------------------"
/usr/bin/git daemon --export-all --enable=receive-pack --verbose --pid-file=/home/git/git-daemon.pid --base-path=/home/git/repos >> /home/git/git-daemon.out 2>> /home/git/git-daemon.err &
echo "---------------------"
echo "STARTED at `date`"
```

stop.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# --------------------------
echo "---------------------"
pkill -F /home/git/git-daemon.pid
echo "---------------------"
echo "STOPPED at `date`"
```

bounce.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# --------------------------
echo "====================="
/home/git/scripts/stop.sh
echo "====================="
sleep 5
echo "====================="
/home/git/scripts/start.sh
echo "====================="
echo "BOUNCED"
```

and status.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# --------------------------
echo "====================="
ps -x --forest
echo "====================="
```

Finally I created a service file (git-daemon.service)...

```
[Unit]
Description=Git Daemon
Documentation=man:git-daemon(1)
ConditionPathExists=/home/git/repos

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/git/gitT start
ExecStop=/bin/bash /home/git/gitT stop
RemainAfterExit=yes
User=git
Group=git

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then I set it up with these commands...

```
cp /home/git/git-daemon.service /etc/systemd/system
systemctl enable git-daemon.service
```

Now if I run `gitT start` as the git user, everything starts fine.  But it I run `systemctl start git-daemon` as root, this is the error...

```
fatal: base-path '/home/git/repos' does not exist or is not a directory
```

Comment: Does `/home/git/repos` exist at the time unit is to be started?

Comment: Yes, it exists. I confirm this by writing a test into the start script prior to executing the git-daemon, and it was positive.

Comment: The error appears to come from `git-daemon` not from `systemd`. But is there is a change if `ConditionPathExists=/home/git/repos` is removed?  Also, what is the output of `ls -ld /home/git/repos`? Maybe it's a permissions issue and the error message is not accurate.

Comment: I’ve tried it with and without the condition with no change.   Permission shouldn’t be an issue since the directory is owned by the git user and set 775.

Answer (score 2):

You have created a system that is significantly more complicated to debug then needs to by duplicating a number of pieces of `systemd` functionality in unnecessary shell scripts. `systemd` has built-in facilities to start, stop and restart services, provide their status and handle their output.

By removing this layer of complexity, you will have eliminated a significant surface area where bugs can exist and will be that much closer to solving your problem.

I recommend using one of existing templates already posted online for managing `git-daemon` with systemd if your system doesn't already ship one.

### References

- [Difference between systemd and terminal starting program](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/339645/20239)
- https://gist.github.com/jeremiah/32d7e696e86ca205509dfa5f9918ad3e
- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Git-Daemon

Comment: [It would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.