# Running dot net application as daemon

Tags: systemd, daemon, c#, net

I have been trying to run a simple dot net application as a daemon. I took a help from many of the below given links and did as suggested.
Links:

1. http://pmcgrath.net/running-a-simple-dotnet-core-linux-daemon
2. https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/06/07/writing-a-linux-daemon-in-c/
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50514114/dotnet-app-started-as-daemon-doesnt-working-properly

I have followed all the standard steps given in all the above links but received a common error in all and couldn't find any resolution online.

Below is the log which I get when I run the command:
*sudo systemctl status console1.service*

[image]

If anyone having any idea why I am getting these it would be of great help. I am stuck here for last 2 days.

Comment: Does the app work when you run it directly (not with systemd)? Your output indicates "code=dumped". Sounds like a core dump, which might be triggered by a software flaw.

Comment: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/

Comment: @MarkStosberg Yes the code works fine when running without systemd

Comment: Please review the FAQ about why things work differently under systemd and see if one of those cases applies to you. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/339645/20239