# Maven application runs alone but not with systemd

Tags: rhel, systemd, maven

I am trying to run [Sphinx4-Http-server](https://github.com/jitsi/Sphinx4-HTTP-server) on RHEL. If I am in the directory `/home/alex/Sphinx4-HTTP-server` and run the command `/home/alex/apache-maven-3.6.1/bin/mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.jitsi.sphinx4http.server.HttpServer"`, then the server will run. However, when I make a `.service` file for the program (as shown below), I get a program error (specifically `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: "org.jitsi.sphinx4http.server.HttpServer"`). Using this file on Ubuntu works (with adjusted path names), and using similar `.service` files for other programs on RHEL works. Why would the program run in the shell but not with systemd, even though the systemd file works on another system and similar systemd files work on the same system? How would I go about fixing it?

`sphinx.service`:

```
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/alex/Sphinx4-HTTP-server
ExecStart=/home/alex/apache-maven-3.6.1/bin/mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.jitsi.sphinx4http.server.HttpServer"
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=sphinx
User=alex

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49482664/9447571

Comment: @filbranden, thanks, but it still fails when systemd is run as `root`. I've also looked at all the solutions suggested at "[Why doesn't my app work under systemd when I can run it directly?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339638/difference-between-systemd-and-terminal-starting-program/339645#339645)", but none of them appear to apply here.

Comment: Maybe take another look at environment variables, I'd say that's the most likely source of discrepancy here. Are you setting any related to classpath in the profile or rc file of the user? Perhaps looking for classes in the current directory is not the default and you're overriding it somewhere in the environment? I'm not very familiar with Maven, so I couldn't tell for sure... But that's where I'd look next.

Answer (score 1):

After some research and trying various fixes out, it seems the solution was number 6 on "[Why doesn't my app work under systemd when I can run it directly?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339638/difference-between-systemd-and-terminal-starting-program/339645#339645)".

Instead of using

```
ExecStart=/home/alex/apache-maven-3.6.1/bin/mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.jitsi.sphinx4http.server.HttpServer"
```

I needed to use the line

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/home/linguini/apache-maven-3.6.1/bin/mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.jitsi.sphinx4http.server.HttpServer"'
```

The important part was running `/bin/bash -c ''` to run the command in the proper shell.