# Bourne shell: what does it execute on interactive, non-login?

Tags: interactive, bourne-shell

I ask in that way, because according to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46856/84749, when I start `screen` it's an "interactive, non-login" I'm doing. What's actually happening is I'm logging into a Bourne shell (not BASH) system, and when I do, it runs `~/.profile` just fine, and sets up my aliases. But when I run `screen` these aliases are lost, and it doesn't seem to run `~/.profile` or `~/.login` or anything else I've tried.

I'm running LibreELEC on a Raspberry Pi 3.

Comment: @kusalananda Ok, i was mistaken then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A login `sh` session reads the user's `~/.profile` upon invocation. If the `ENV` variable is set to a filename after doing that, and if that file exists, the shell will use that file to further initialize the login session.

Interactive shells that are not login shells will only use `$ENV` if `ENV` is set, but will not read `~/.profile`.

Non-interactive shell should not use either of these two files.

Usually, one exports `ENV` at the end of one's `~/.profile`:

```
ENV="$HOME/.shrc"     # for example
export ENV            # may be done as export ENV="..." too, in most shells.
```

This is, for example, what `bash` does if it's invoked as `sh` or with `bash --posix`.

One may use these two files (`~/.profile` and `$ENV`) for whatever one wishes, but the profile is where you might want to set and export environment variables that only needs to be set once (`PATH` etc.), fire up any `fetchmail` process or other user daemon that you wish to use etc., while the `$ENV` file is where you set up specific things for this particular shell session/TTY, such as setting `GPG_TTY` (if you're using GnuPG), setting up aliases (since aliases are not inherited by subshells) etc.

The `ksh93` shell uses `~/.profile` and `$ENV` by default, but interprets `$ENV` in a specific way. *If* `$ENV` starts with `/./` or `././`, then no system-wide configuration file will be used (e.g. `/etc/ksh.kshrc`).

The file `~/.login` is not used by `sh`, unless `ENV` is set to this filename or it is explicitly sourced from `~/.profile` or `$ENV`.

Comment: I know you could export variables, but I didn't think you can do it w/aliases. According to http://superuser.com/a/447529/398620 you can't. In any case, I tried w/`export alias l='ls -lF'` in `~/.profile`. Not only did it not make it to my non-login but the alias was lost in my login.

Comment: @PenguinLust No, you can't export aliases, but you can set `ENV` to a filename that contains your alias initializations.